# utf8x vs. utf8 (inputenc)

Tags: unicode, best-practices, input-encodings

I normally use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` for my latex document but on this site i saw a lot of code with `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`.

What are the differences between the 2 options ?

Is there one of the option obsolete and which one should I use ?

Comment: Collection of incompatibilities of utf8x: [1 (DeclareUnicodeCharacter)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127975/ucs-clashes-with-declareunicodechar) [2 (csquotes)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50712/automatically-convert-quotations-in-the-form-of-abc-to-become-abc#comment1137397_50733) [3 (hyperref)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/654000/argument-of-has-an-extra)

Comment: **Note**: in the newest version (August 2022) `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` does nothing, you need `\usepackage{ucs}` before it in addition. Refer to the update note in the manual in https://ctan.org/pkg/ucs  for details.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

The simple answer is that `utf8x` is to be avoided if possible. It loads the `ucs` package, which for a long time was unmaintained (although there is now a new maintainer) and breaks various other things.

See [egreg's answer to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/203804) as well, which outlines how to get extra characters using the `[utf8]` option of `inputenc`.

Generally, however, the best way to deal with Unicode source (especially with non-latin scripts) is really XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

There's an extended discussion of this here: [Encoding remarks](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/comp.text.tex/4LC-xODb-LU/1Bd5UZOMNM4J).  See especially the comments by Philipp Lehman and Philipp Stephani.

Comment: In some case `utf8` breaks some things too when `utf8x` is fine. I work only with `utf8` and `utf8x` and I don't remember why but after working with `utf8` and some problems, now  I work with `utf8x`. I agree with you about  XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX but some users need to work again with pdflatex.

Comment: usually I use LuaLaTeX, but for some stuff I don't have choice to use pdfLaTeX

Comment: The link to "encoding remarks" above seems to be broken, and I can't seem to find the right object. Does anyone know how to relocate this (apparently important) discussion?

Comment: @acr I've fixed the broken link.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Don't forget to remove `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` before compiling with XeLaTex (and BTW replace the `fontenc` package by `fontspec`).

Answer (score 51):

In fact, `utf8` may not be as restrictive as it seems: it only loads characters that can be displayed by the font encoding.

When typing

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

the font encoding is still `OT1` when loading `inputenc`, which has very few characters. By using

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

you will allow all displayable utf8 characters to be available as input.

Comment: I think I am blind but I see no difference between those two lines... Except for what seems to be a typo in "userpackage"

Comment: @drozzy, the difference is the order of the commands.

Comment: Could you provide an example of a character unavailable in first case but available in the second case?

Comment: This is just wrong. First, it is just not true that the order affects the available input characters. This is easy to establish. Try the string `æ ç ð â`. Second, characters available in the input encoding are certainly not restricted to those in the output encoding. If they were, `utf8x` would not support typesetting `ŵ ŷ` with the T1 font encoding. (T1 does not include these characters. Yet they are acceptable input with `utf8x` and they can be typeset to display correctly by combining the accent with the vowel.)

Comment: @cfr How can a wrong answer can get 42 upvotes? :)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner This must be your first day on the internet: welcome ;).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Actually, it has 46 upvotes. It also has 4 downvotes.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner The answer is no longer +42, so I believe it is wrong once more.

Comment: Remark, it's "only" half wrong. `utf8` indeed load only characters that can be represented in the font encoding, but if the font encoding is loaded later `utf8` can **still handle it**. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82411/problem-with-%E1%BA%BD-tilde-and-utf8#comment1567595_82412 . // Besides, characters that can be displayed by the font encoding **includes those that can be displayed with an accent**, so the second issue in [cfr's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13067/utf8x-vs-utf8-inputenc/34046#comment476003_34046) above is not a problem.

Answer (score 48):

Don't use `utf8x`; with an up-to-date TeX distribution it could show necessary only for its most obscure features (faking characters with images from the Web, for instance).

The problem with Greek, which was probably the main reason for adopting `utf8x` instead of `utf8`, have since be solved and

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

This is english
\textgreek{Τηις ις γρεεκ}
This is english again.

\end{document}
```

will happily print

[image]

The occasional missing definitions can be coped with in a simple way. If you're able to input a Unicode character, such as the Welsh letters

```
Ââ Êê Îî Ôô Ŵŵ Ŷŷ Ïï
```

or the Latin vowels with prosodic marks

```
Ăă Ĕĕ Ĭĭ Ŏŏ Ŭŭ Āā Ēē Īī Ōō Ūū Ȳȳ
```

(y with breve is missing from Unicode, while a with breve is already defined by `utf8` because it's a letter in Romanian), you can simply add the unknown ones to the list of known characters:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

% missing Welsh coverage
\newunicodechar{Ŵ}{\^W}
\newunicodechar{ŵ}{\^w}
\newunicodechar{Ŷ}{\^Y}
\newunicodechar{ŷ}{\^y}

% Latin vowels with prosodic marks    
\newunicodechar{Ĕ}{\u{E}}
\newunicodechar{ĕ}{\u{e}}
\newunicodechar{Ĭ}{\u{I}}
\newunicodechar{ĭ}{\u{\i}}
\newunicodechar{Ŏ}{\u{O}}
\newunicodechar{ŏ}{\u{o}}
\newunicodechar{Ŭ}{\u{U}}
\newunicodechar{ŭ}{\u{u}}
\newunicodechar{Ā}{\=A}
\newunicodechar{ā}{\=a}
\newunicodechar{Ē}{\=E}
\newunicodechar{ē}{\=e}
\newunicodechar{Ī}{\=I}
\newunicodechar{ī}{\={\i}}
\newunicodechar{Ō}{\=O}
\newunicodechar{ō}{\=o}
\newunicodechar{Ū}{\=U}
\newunicodechar{ū}{\=u}
\newunicodechar{Ȳ}{\=Y}
\newunicodechar{ȳ}{\=y}

\begin{document}

Ââ Êê Îî Ôô Ŵŵ Ŷŷ Ïï

Ăă Ĕĕ Ĭĭ Ŏŏ Ŭŭ

Āā Ēē Īī Ōō Ūū Ȳȳ

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that, for instance, the line

```
\newunicodechar{Ŵ}{\^W}
```

can be also input as

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0174}{\^W}
```

without the need of the `newunicodechar` package, because `U+0174` is the code point of LATIN CAPITAL LETTER W WITH CIRCUMFLEX; but `\newunicodechar` frees from looking up in the Unicode tables.

---

## Update, April 2016

With a recent LaTeX kernel almost none of the definitions above is necessary, because `T1enc.dfu` has been updated and enriched. Of the accented letters in the last example, only `Ȳ` and `ȳ` need to be defined (and they'll possibly be included in next releases).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{Ȳ}{\=Y}
\newunicodechar{ȳ}{\=y}

\begin{document}

Ââ Êê Îî Ôô Ŵŵ Ŷŷ Ïï

Ăă Ĕĕ Ĭĭ Ŏŏ Ŭŭ

Āā Ēē Īī Ōō Ūū Ȳȳ

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Update 2021

Now all those accented letters are defined in the kernel. So the following works out of the box. Note that `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is not strictly required; however, loading it is better because it contains many precomposed accented letters.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

Ââ Êê Îî Ôô Ŵŵ Ŷŷ Ïï

Ăă Ĕĕ Ĭĭ Ŏŏ Ŭŭ

Āā Ēē Īī Ōō Ūū Ȳȳ

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just a note: it seems also `ﬁ` (LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FI) is not in `[utf8]{inputenc}`, only in `[utf8x]{inputenc}` (which in my case is good: it alerted me to `ﬁ`'s existence - which is an artifact of copypaste - in a bibtex file, which the previous `utf8x` document didn't notice).

Comment: and do we have to do that by hand for the thousands of characters out there ????

Comment: @nicolas Happily, newer LaTeX kernels contain many more combinations than it used to do two years ago.

Comment: @egreg See my updated answer below. The code you've given is no longer required for the to bach on Welsh vowels.

Comment: @cfr Yes, the code can be reduced to a bare minimum. `:-)`

Comment: I stumbled by chance upon this answer: I can confirm that the remaining letters have been added. The MWE works now without any `\newunicodechar`.

Comment: Can you please help, if I want to use `$\alpha$` instead of `\alpha` what do I change in the `\userpackage`? It is giving me an error on overleaf when I use `$\alpha$`

Comment: @FareedAF That's not really clear. Please, ask a new question on the main page.

Comment: Update now: you no longer have to define `Ŷŷ`. (you may want to move the newer part to the top, or just delete the old part completely or note "for version ≥ X" -- there's the revision history

Comment: @user202729 Thanks for reminding.

Comment: What is the benefit of"precomposed accented letters"? I assume better for copy and paste?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Not only that, but also hyphenation, because composed accents block it.

Answer (score 22):

"The simple answer is that `utf8x` is to be avoided if possible."
Yes and No. No it's not so simple `utf8x` is sometimes necessary when you need to write greek or some special symbols. Yes `utf8x` is for a long time was unmaintained but we can use it.
Try to compile the next code with `utf8`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,english]{babel}

\renewcommand*{\textgreek}[1]{%
  \foreignlanguage{greek}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

This is english
\textgreek{Τηις ις γρεεκ}
This is english again.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: utfx is not necessary for greek. utf8 is extensible: You need a lgrenc.dfu to get the definition for greek then utf8 will work fine. lgrenc.dfu can be found on the net (e.g. in the latex bug database if I remember it correctly).

Comment: @Ulrike: Thanks Ulrike, I don't know 'lgrenc.dfu' ! Is it recent ? Josselin Noirel writes something about "mem.sty" but I think this package disappears. `\usepackage[charset=utf8,greek,english]{mem}`

Comment: @Ulrike: Why lgrenc.dfu is not in TeXLive ? and I read : Based on a babel patch by Werner Lemberg, with input from the ucs package (ucsencs.def) by Dominique Unruh and CB.enc by Apostolos Syropoulos. So there is a part from ucs !

Comment: I have no idea why it never found its way to CTAN. But it is not part of ucs, it only reused some (or a lot) definitions from it (writing all this long list which maps a input char to a command is a lot work). lgrenc.dfu is quite similar to standard lists like t1enc.dfu and utf8enc.def which are part of basic latex/inputenc+utf8.

Comment: Useful: http://milde.users.sourceforge.net/LGR/

Comment: In TeX Live 2012 one can say `\usepackage[LGRx,T1]{fontenc}` and then `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` will enable direct usage of Greek characters.

Comment: And since TeX Live 2013, `LGRx` is not necessary any more (it should actually be removed, see [`lgrxenc.def` not found](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191685/)

Comment: With current TeX Live the result with `utf8` is the same as the shown, isn't it?

Answer (score 13):

I've had the experience of not being able to compile Hebrew with `utf8`, only with `utf8x`, using pdflatex in MikTeX (e.g. 2.9). Many guides on writing Hebrew LaTeX suggest using `utf8x`:

- [ivritex](http://ivritex.sourceforge.net/HOWTO/heblatex_guide_u8.html)
- [A Hebrew wikibook on LaTeX](http://he.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%98%D7%9A/%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%AA)
- [The Hebrew Wikipedia LaTeX article](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX)
- [Yoav Goldberg' Hebrew LaTeX tips page at BGU](http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~yoavg/tech-notes/heblatex/)
- etc.

This is not to contradict what the learned sages say above, it's just an example of a case in which it seems to be impossible to avoid (unless someone suggests a way like Ulrike's suggesting regarding Greek).

**Note**: This answer is only relevant to pdfTeX+Babel, not XeTeX+Polyglossia.

Comment: Frankly, if you are working with Hebrew, you should really be using XeLaTeX and the `bidi` package.

Comment: Well, I was talking in the past tense... although, frankly, I haven't made the switch yet. Still find it important to mention it here, as people looking up the difference between the two options will probably hit this question.

Comment: XeLaTeX must have been a great improvement for people writing in Hebrew. I don't think the incompatibility between `babel` with the `hebrew` option and `amsthm` was ever fixed (I don't write Hebrew myself, so I never bothered to check)

Comment: @kahen: It's true fundamentally, but the package support is still lacking - even more with XeLaTeX+polyglossia than with pdfLaTeX+babel.

Comment: As of 2021, Hebrew now works for either Babel or Polyglossia in either LuaTeX or XeTeX (I normally use Babel in LuaTeX myself), but the legacy `ivritex` or `culmus-latex` packages for PDFTeX still require `utf8z`.

Answer (score 11):

> **Update**
>   The `utf8x` option is no longer required.
>
> The following now works unproblematically (except that certain characters are composed on-the-fly, but that's another matter).
>
> ```
> \documentclass[welsh]{article}
> \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
> \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
> \usepackage{babel}
> \begin{document}
>
>  Ââ Êê Îî Ôô Ûû Ŵŵ Ŷŷ Ïï
>
> \end{document}
> ```

## Original answer

*This answer is now deprecated and applies only for older installations. If your installation of TeX is current, you should **not** need `utf8x` any longer. `utf8` should now be sufficient.*

Welsh requires `utf8x` as the characters ŵ and ŷ are not recognised otherwise:

```
\documentclass[welsh]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

 Ââ Êê Îî Ôô Ŵŵ Ŷŷ Ïï

\end{document}
```

Obviously, XeLaTeX is an option although `babel` is still required as `polyglossia` doesn't support Welsh.

Comment: `\usepackage{newunicodechar}\newunicodechar{ŵ}{\^w}` (works with the `utf8` option). Of course this breaks hyphenation, but it's the same with `utf8x`

Comment: @egreg Yes, but then you have to add it for every additional accented character you need whereas `utf8x` is just typing an additional `x`. It doesn't break hyphenation generally, though - only for cases where words containing those characters would be hyphenated? Is that right? (Those words will not be very common. `^` generally occurs on short words or words which are hyphenated anyway. `gwdihŵ` would be an example but the most common cases are things like `tŷ`.)

Comment: I wouldn't use a package that's known to be fragile and that breaks easily just in order to avoid a couple of definitions. You should make a feature request to the LaTeX team that they add the Welsh characters to `utf8`.

Comment: @egreg I finally figured out how to do that from David Carlisle. Hence, http://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=latex/4400.

Comment: While it may be annoying having to do that for all documents in Welsh, you can see from my answer that all it takes is five lines of code.

Comment: @egreg I don't claim to be entirely rational about this. However, I'm currently only typesetting small amounts of Welsh and it doesn't include any of those characters so right now I'm neither using `utf8x` nor declaring the additions. Though clearly this situation is fragile in itself.

Comment: I can't believe anyone who wants to use obscure characters like  Σ ⇛ ⇒ would have to do this by hand. that's so wrong..

Comment: @nicolas I don't think I have to any more. Despite David's initial scepticism, I think ŵ, ŷ etc. are now included. For the mathematical symbols, though, I guess it is a bit different. Do you really type those directly rather than using macros? That wouldn't even occur to me, to be honest.

Comment: @cfr yes I input them directly. haskell, agda, among a few languages, perfectly support that. It is so amazing that a system whose purpose is dedicated to such specialized typing would not support it natively....  I am fuming..

Comment: @nicolas Why don't you use XeTeX or LuaTeX? Really, it is not that surprising that traditional TeX engines don't support this given the time at which they were written and the kind of computer resources available.

Comment: @cfr I tried and it did not work, but your suggestion made me loot at it again. apparently there are some form of initialization steps I did not perform correctly. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Just to point out another issue with `utf8x`, which I come across while digging through the documentation of the "historical" package `inpmath`: the kerning is "more likely" to be wrong.

```
%! TEX program = pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

% either...
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

% or...
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% unfortunately if the encoding is OT1 then the kerning will break for both package

\begin{document}
VÁ

V\'A
\end{document}
```

In the first case only `inputenc` gives the correct kerning, `ucs` does not. In the second case you can see the correct kerning.

Output with `ucs`:

[image: output 1]

Output with `inputenc`:

[image: output 2]

The first row uses the Unicode character in the input directly, the second row uses the TeX command form `\'A` (which always work).

Normally fonts should set the kerning so that the gap between `V` and `A` are smaller, but the effect does not work in the `ucs` case as shown above.

The underlying reason is that `utf8x` executes some *unexpandable* command to process each Unicode character.

Comment: It’s not clear what you mean by “only `inputenc` gives the correct kerning”.

Comment: @egreg Just compile and see like that?

Comment: I wasn't doubting; the problem is that the phrase I mentioned is very unclear.

Comment: The real problem is that `uni-0.def` is loaded when `Á` is scanned, not before processing text. What's missing is a link between output encodings and `uni-n.def` files. The `ucs` package should load at begin document the `def` files corresponding to the wanted output encodings (like it's done with the `dfu` files when using the `utf8` option). One can “solve” the issue by adding something like `\PrerenderUnicode{Á}` in the preamble or at begin document.