# Why do hyperref and harvard not work together properly?

Tags: hyperref, citing, natbib, harvard-style

In my current work, I cannot seem to get the packages `harvard` and `hyperref` to work together properly.

A small example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{cite}

\usepackage{harvard}
\citationmode{abbr}
\bibliographystyle{dcu}

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0},pdftitle={the document title},pdfauthor={the author}]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=false}


\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

The error message I get is:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
```

in the line right after `\usepackage[...]{hyperref}`.

As soon as I either remove the `harvard` package, the document compiles flawlessly. The same happens when I remove the `hyperref` package.

What bugs me: When I remove the options from `\usepackage[...]{hyperref}`, it also works.

Does anybody know what problem I am facing?

**EDIT:**

Sometimes, reading the error log in more detail helps. Seems, that missing \begin{document} was not the root cause, but rather the error further down in the log:

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.43
The package hyperref has already been loaded with options:
[pdftex]
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
[pdfborder={0 0 0},pdftitle={the document title},pdfauthor={the author}]
Adding the global options:
pdftex,pdfborder={0 0 0},pdftitle={the document title},pdfauthor={the author}
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
```

I have no idea why, but the package seems to be loaded automatically, when I use pdflatex to compile my document. I ended up using

```
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=false}
\hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 0}}
\hypersetup{pdftitle={\thetitle}}
\hypersetup{pdfauthor={\theauthor}}
```

**EDIT 2**

As per Marco Daniel's request:

```
*File List*
scrreprt.cls 2009/07/24 v3.04a KOMA-Script document class (report)
scrkbase.sty 2009/07/24 v3.04a KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent ba
sics and keyval usage)
scrbase.sty 2009/07/24 v3.04a KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent
basics and keyval usage)
keyval.sty 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty 2009/03/25 v3.03 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
tocbasic.sty 2009/06/08 v3.03b KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize12pt.clo 2009/07/24 v3.04a KOMA-Script font size class option (12pt)
typearea.sty 2009/07/24 v3.04a KOMA-Script package (type area)
inputenc.sty 2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
utf8x.def 2004/10/17 UCS: Input encoding UTF-8
ucs.sty 2004/10/17 UCS: Unicode input support
uni-global.def 2004/10/17 UCS: Unicode global data
times.sty 2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a (SPQR)
url.sty 2006/04/12 ver 3.3 Verb mode for urls, etc.
xcolor.sty 2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
dvips.def 1999/02/16 v3.0i Driver-dependant file (DPC,SPQR)
dvipsnam.def 1999/02/16 v3.0i Driver-dependant file (DPC,SPQR)
graphicx.sty 1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty 2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
trig.sty 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg 2009/08/28 v1.8 graphics configuration of TeX Live
rotating.sty 2009/03/28 v2.16a rotated objects in LaTeX
ifthen.sty 2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
listings.sty 2007/02/22 1.4 (Carsten Heinz)
lstmisc.sty 2007/02/22 1.4 (Carsten Heinz)
listings.cfg 2007/02/22 1.4 listings configuration
fancyhdr.sty
cite.sty 2009/08/29 v 5.2
harvard.sty
html.sty 1999/07/19 v1.38 hypertext commands for latex2html (nd, hws, rr
m)
setspace.sty 2000/12/01 6.7 Contributed and Supported LaTeX2e package
hyperref.sty 2009/10/09 v6.79a Hypertext links for LaTeX
ifpdf.sty 2009/04/10 v2.0 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
ifvtex.sty 2008/11/04 v1.4 Switches for detecting VTeX and its modes (HO)
ifxetex.sty 2009/01/23 v0.5 Provides ifxetex conditional
hycolor.sty 2009/10/02 v1.5 Code for color options of hyperref/bookmark (HO
)
xcolor-patch.sty 2009/10/02 xcolor patch
pd1enc.def 2009/10/09 v6.79a Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
etexcmds.sty 2007/12/12 v1.2 Prefix for e-TeX command names (HO)
infwarerr.sty 2007/09/09 v1.2 Providing info/warning/message (HO)
hyperref.cfg 2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
kvoptions.sty 2009/08/13 v3.4 Keyval support for LaTeX options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty 2009/07/30 v1.5 Key value parser with default handler support
(HO)
bitset.sty 2007/09/28 v1.0 Data type bit set (HO)
intcalc.sty 2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable integer calculations (HO)
bigintcalc.sty 2007/11/11 v1.1 Expandable big integer calculations (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty 2009/09/23 v0.6 LuaTeX support for pdfTeX utility functions (
HO)
ifluatex.sty 2009/04/17 v1.2 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
ltxcmds.sty 2009/08/05 v1.0 Some LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
atbegshi.sty 2008/07/31 v1.9 At begin shipout hook (HO)
hdvips.def 2009/10/09 v6.79a Hyperref driver for dvips
pdfmark.def 2009/10/09 v6.79a Hyperref definitions for pdfmark specials
ot1ptm.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ptm.
ucsencs.def 2003/11/29 Fixes to fontencodings LGR, T3
nameref.sty 2007/05/29 v2.31 Cross-referencing by name of section
refcount.sty 2008/08/11 v3.1 Data extraction from references (HO)
minimalbeispiel.out
minimalbeispiel.out
```

Comment: Please compare my file list with your file list. You see you need an update of all you packages.

Comment: I'm using the packaged latex environment that is shipped with Ubuntu 11.10, I don't really want to mess with this installation. I'm glad it works (more or less, hence the question ;-) )

Comment: Without the installation of TeX Live 2011 you must install all packages and the dependencies manual. See (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LaTeX#TeX_Live)

Comment: If I try with TeX Live 2009 the example does not compile, but by a different reason. However it's an updated 2009, not the distribution coming with Ubuntu that's frozen as of October 2009; I suspect that at the time harvard and hyperref were indeed incompatible, probably because there's a package `html.sty` that harvard loads.

Comment: Maybe that's the point. I will try to update my environment right _after_ the deadline for my document ;-). Thanks so much!

Comment: @egreg: It was precisely this "habit" of `harvard` to load the `html` package that was giving me grief a couple of years ago. I ended up switching to the `natbib` and `har2nat` packages and haven't experienced those difficulties since. :-) See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 6):

I can't answer your question directly, but I can suggest a workaround that is just about fail-safe: Instead of loading the `harvard` bibliography citation manager, load both the `natbib` and `har2nat` packages. `Natbib` is known to work very well with `hyperref`, and the `har2nat` package "translates" all `harvard`-type citation commands into equivalent `natbib`-type citation commands. That way, you can keep using all of your `harvard`-style citation commands, but they'll be processed by `natbib` from now on. :-)

Before you (re)run latex and bibtex on your latex file, you should probably delete the various auxiliary files, as they contain information in "harvard"-style rather than "natbib"-style directives.

I made this switch (from `harvard` to `natbib`, with help from the `har2nat` package) a couple of years ago, after I ran into problems caused by interactions with `hyperref` -- more or less the same problems as you describe in your posting. I've not experienced these problems since then. :-)

*Some additional comments* about your document's preamble, not related to the harvard-hyperref interaction issue:

- The `times` package is obsolete; consider loading `mathptmx`.
- You needn't load the `cite` package if you load either the `harvard` or the `natbib` package. (Both packages redefine LaTeX's `\cite` command, disabling whatever functionality is provided by the `cite` package.)
- The command `\hypersetup{colorlinks=false}` is unnecessary since you've already specified the option `pdfborder=...` when loading the `hyperref` package.

Comment: I tried this and it works. Without using `harvard` it compiles well. But I'm curious: What advantages does natbib have over harvard?

Comment: Delighted to learn that the suggested method works for you! I'd say the main advantage of using the `natbib` instead of `harvard` is its great inter-operability with hyperref! :-) In addition, `natbib` provides a few more commands that aren't provided by `harvard`. Natbib was created *after* harvard had been around, and it consciously was designed to provide all of harvard's capabilities natively while also providing some new commands.

Comment: I've heard the advice about har2nat and natbib a few times, and am finally making the switch to natbib, but I notice that in TeXlive 2014 (as well as in earlier versions that I've tried in the past), har2nat doesn't actually define all the harvard commands.  E.g., I still end up having to define a version of `\possessivecite`:  `\newcommand{\possessivecite}[1]{\citeauthor{#1}'s \citeyearpar{#1}}`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor - You're absolutely correct, the package `har2nat` provides no "translation" for the `\possessivcite` macro of the `harvard` package. Not having occasion to ever use this particular macro, I hadn't noticed this omission until now.

Comment: Yes, a few omissions like that have actually kept me away from natbib+har2nat until now.  The har2nat [documentation](http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/macros/latex/contrib/har2nat/har2nat.pdf) says that it should be as easy as replacing the `\usepackage{harvard}` with `\usepackage{natbib} \usepackage{har2nat}`, but har2nat doesn't actually "[contain all] the citation commands provided by the Harvard package", (e.g., possessivecite, citationmode, the various `*` and `**` citation commands), so it's not quite as easy as the documentation suggests.

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: The OP uses TeX Live 2009 which was installed by synaptic. In the [wiki of ubuntu community](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LaTeX#TeX_Live) you can read the following note:

> As of October 2011 the texlive package that ships with Ubuntu (TeX
>   Live 2009) is [**lagging more than two years behind the current TeX Live
>   release**](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texlive-base/+bug/712521) (TeX Live 2011). If you don't have big space constraints and
>   want the latest version of TeX Live, you can install it directly from
>   [the TeX Live website](http://www.tug.org/texlive/) (this does not interfere with the packages in
>   Ubuntu).

---

I got no errors with your example. Some hints:

1. Please have a look at this answer: [Avoiding utf8x](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13067/utf8x-vs-utf8-inputenc)
2. Don't use the package `ucs` which is loaded by `utf8x` per default
3. You don't need to load the package `url`. `hyperref` do the job.

Here my file list to compare:

```
 *File List*
scrreprt.cls    2011/06/16 v3.09a KOMA-Script document class (report)
scrkbase.sty    2011/06/16 v3.09a KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent ba
sics and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2011/06/16 v3.09a KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent 
basics and keyval usage)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty    2011/03/09 v3.09 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
tocbasic.sty    2011/05/30 v3.09a KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize12pt.clo    2011/06/16 v3.09a KOMA-Script font size class option (12pt)
typearea.sty    2011/06/16 v3.09a KOMA-Script package (type area)
inputenc.sty    2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   times.sty    2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a (SPQR) 
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/message (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/04/18 v1.20 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
dvipsnam.def    1999/02/16 v3.0i Driver-dependant file (DPC,SPQR)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
rotating.sty    2009/03/28 v2.16a rotated objects in LaTeX
  ifthen.sty    2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
listings.sty    2007/02/22 1.4 (Carsten Heinz)
 lstmisc.sty    2007/02/22 1.4 (Carsten Heinz)
listings.cfg    2007/02/22 1.4 listings configuration
fancyhdr.sty    
    cite.sty    2010/09/10  v 5.3
 harvard.sty    
setspace.sty    2000/12/01 6.7 Contributed and Supported LaTeX2e package
hyperref.sty    2011/10/01 v6.82j Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2011/04/23 v1.4 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2011/04/23 v1.4 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2011/04/23 v1.4 Subsetting bundle oberdiek (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Switches for detecting VTeX and its modes (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable integer calculations (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Prefix for e-TeX command names (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.13 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Defining keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/04/22 v0.16 Utilities of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/04/04 v1.12 Provides string conversions (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Expandable big integer calculations (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Data type bit set (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provides unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2011/01/30 v1.0 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/04/23 v1.7 Hooks at very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/01/30 v1.15 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2010/12/01 v3.2 Data extraction from references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options of hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
kvoptions.sty    2010/12/23 v3.10 Keyval support for LaTeX options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2011/10/01 v6.82j Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 hpdftex.def    2011/10/01 v6.82j Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
  ot1ptm.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ptm.
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Managing graphics extensions (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 nameref.sty    2010/04/30 v2.40 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
    test.out
    test.out
 ***********
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however this was not my case here. When I removed `ucs` and `utf8x`, I still got the same error.

Comment: @Cassy: Please put the command `\listfiles` to your header and than you will find the file list in the log-file.

Comment: Thanks again. See my own answer regarding pdflatex. Obviously, it's not a matter of the packages, but rather of the calling program.

Comment: Nothing special: `\newcommand{\thetitle}{here be the title}` I just forgot to remove this from the second snippet

Answer (score 4):

The `harvard` package loads the `html` package, if it exists, which loads `hyperref`. From `harvard.sty`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{harvard}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\IfFileExists{html.sty}{\RequirePackage{html}
...
```

Possible solutions:

- Instead of loading `hyperref` with options yourself, you could use `\hypersetup`. This is recommended.
- In this and similar cases one could use `\PassOptionsToPackage{...}{packagename}`.
- Another option is specifiying hyperref options to the document class, which would be inherited. I would not prefer that generally, as further packages might be affected.
- Deinstalling `html.sty` and deactivating auto package installation
- Putting a dummy `html.sty` into your document folder could fix it, however it would be bad to have different style files with the same name - just to mention it and suggesting not to do it.

Note, `hyperref` should be loaded at the end of the preamble, [with some exceptions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before), so load `harvard` in the same sense like `hyperref` at the end of the preamble to avoid problems.