# "TeX capacity exceeded" with harvard package and url fields in bib file

Tags: bibtex, errors, harvard-style

When I try to compile the attached test document with MikTeX 2.9 updated to the latest packages, I get a

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
```

error.  I finally tracked down the error to be caused by the `url` line in the bib file, which my bib manager automatically produces.  How can I fix this without manually removing all `url` lines (which I don't need most of the time, but I don't understand why they lead to the error)?

---

The commands I used for compilation are

```
pdflatex sa
bibtex sa
pdflatex sa
```

Please obtain the `iopart` class files from [here](http://authors.iop.org/atom/help.nsf/0/B042B0AF79C815B88025702000409514?OpenDocument&journalid=NJP) (I used the PKZip version).  I extracted *all* files from the zip to my project directory and followed the instructions from the documentation included in the same zip file:

> - for alphabetic (Harvard) style reference we recommend that authors use
>     the jphysicsB.bst BiBTeX style file together with the harvard LATEX
>     package. jphysicsB.bst is supplied as part of the harvard.sty package
>     which can be downloaded from www.ctan.org.

---

Source for `sa.tex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{iopart}
\usepackage{iopams}  
\usepackage{harvard}

\begin{document}

test \cite{Hoo2009}.

\bibliographystyle{jphysicsB}
\bibliography{sa}

\end{document}
```

Source for `sa.bib`:

```
@ARTICLE{Hoo2009,
  author = {Boo Hoo},
  title = {Paper},
  year = {2009},
  url = {boo}
}
```

Comment: Where is a trusted source for `iopart`?

Comment: @egreg I put the link in the question now.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get any error. The problem might be in the presence of an `html.sty` in your system.

Comment: @egreg I remember that file was auto-downloaded by MikTeX when I compiled for the first time.  Do you suggest removing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is similar to the one raised in the question [Why do hyperref and harvard not work together properly?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34258/why-do-hyperref-and-harvard-not-work-together-properly)

The biggest problem is that `harvard.sty` is quite old and it's unclear what `html.sty` it refers to. Currently TeX Live doesn't have an `html.sty` file, but you probably have one as part of `latex2html` (as stated in the http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latex2html page). What is certain is that the `html.sty` file provided by `latex2html` is incompatible with `harvard.sty`

Having an empty `html.sty` file in your working directory (as suggested in an answer) should solve the problem. Another strategy is to use `natbib` and `har2nat`:

```
\usepackage{natbib,har2nat}
\providecommand{\newblock}{}
```

(the second line probably has to do with the fact that `iopart.cls` doesn't define `\newblock`. The output should be very similar to the one produced by `harvard.sty`.