# Harvard Citation Styles "et al." and hyperlinking citations to references

Tags: citing, links, harvard-style

I am using the Harvard package and a Journal of Finance bst file (downloaded from the [home page of Ivo Welch](http://www.ivo-welch.info/computers/bstfiles/)) in a LaTeX document. Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{harvard}

\begin{document}
Citation one from \citeasnoun{Kozhan}, and also citation two from \citeasnoun{Kozhan}.

\bibliographystyle{jf}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

With sample references.bib file:

```
@inproceedings{Kozhan,
  title={The Skew Risk Premium in Index Option Prices},
  author={Kozhan, R. and Neuberger, A. and Schneider, P.},
  booktitle={AFA 2011 Denver Meetings Paper},
  year={2011}
}
```

This prints as:

> Citation one from Kozhan, Neuberger, and Schneider (2011), and also citation two from Kozhan, Neuberger, and Schneider (2011).

I would rather have it as

> Citation one from Kozhan, Neuberger, and Schneider (2011), and also citation two from Kozhan et al. (2011).

The guide on the Harvard citation styles (http://tex.loria.fr/bibdex/harvard.pdf) says:

> [...] where there are more than two authors, all authors are
>   listed in the first citation and in subsequent citations just the first
>   author's name followed by `et al.' is used.

However, as can be seen by the example above, this does not seem to be the case. Why? Finally, how can I hyperlink my citations to the relevant entry in the references section?

Comment: For the hyperlink, add `\usepackage{hyperref}` to your preamble. Note that this should, [with some exceptions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before), be the last package you load.

Comment: I added this package (as the last one), yet the citations are still not hyperlinked.

Comment: Yes, I see. Sorry, that generally works, but apparently not with the `harvard` package. You could perhaps try what Mico mentions in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34264/586), loading `natbib` and `har2nat` instead of `harvard`. (In that case, you have to delete the `.aux` file before compiling again, I think.)

Comment: That worked, thanks! However, I lost my \possessivecite...

Comment: Perhaps a new question about that would be best, if you're unable to figure it out. Oh, and if you want to use `natbib`+`har2nat`, you should update the code in this question.

Answer (score 3):

Concerning losing `\possessivecite`

[This](http://miktex.10937.n7.nabble.com/MiKTeX-2-5-and-Harvard-Style-Bibliographies-td2508.html) worked for me.

Rough syntax:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{har2nat}
\newcommand{\possessivecite}[1]{\citeauthor{#1}'s \citeyearpar{#1}}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: A quick note for future readers of this answer: If all one needs is a definition of `\possessivecite` that works with the `natbib` package, load the `har2nat` package is not necessary. (`har2nat` is only needed if you want to use other commands of the `harvard` citation management package.)