# use \citet with a genitive

Tags: citing, natbib

I'm using the `natbib` package and have a sentence like this:

> Smith's (2000) argument is widely accepted.

If I use `\citet{smith2000}'s`, this will lead to "Smith (2000)'s argument...".

Is there any way to get the desired genitive-s directly behind the name?

Here's my preamble:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\usepackage{longtable} %Muss vor arydslin stehen!
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm} % Math packages
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage[]{float}
\usepackage[authoryear,round,longnamesfirst]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: See [this posting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/104467/5001) for a definition of `\possessivecite` that works with the `natbib` package. (Note that it's not necessary to load the `har2nat` package.) With this macro, you can write `\possessivecite{smith}` to get `Smith's (2000)`.

Comment: cool, it solved my problem! Is it still a duplicate, even if the `\possessivecite` did not occur in the other question originally, but only as an afterthought? In this case, should I delete this question?

Comment: Absolutely no need to delete your question! As you've noted, the older query was mostly about other issue, and the possessive form of citation call-outs arose mostly as a side or afterthought.