# Error produced in citation with agsm style

Tags: bibliographies, citing

My citations are not defined according to the log but then appear in this strange form in my biblography. This is the Code I use:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\documentclass[ngerman,a4paper,pagesize,oneside,headinclude,parskip=half,DIV14,BCOR5mm,12pt,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc]{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{DIV=current}
\pagestyle{headings}
\usepackage{ngerman}        
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage{lmodern}        
\usepackage[gen,right]{eurosym}     
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{scrhack} 
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cite}

\ ...

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\hyphenation{Sil-ben-trenn-ung}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\input{files/00_title.tex}

\linespread{1.25}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\mainmatter
\input{files/ch1}

\appendix
\backmatter
\bibliographystyle{agsm} % Harvard-Style
\bibliography{literatur}

\end{document}
```

And from the bib-file:

```
@Article{thaler81,
Title                    = {Some Empirical Evidence on Dynamic Inconsistency},
Author                   = {Richard Thaler},
Journal                  = {Economic Letters},
Year                     = {1981},
}
```

In ch1, the reference is given by \cite{thaler81}. I used jabref to avoid problems/errors while citing.

[image: generated bibliography]

I'm new to Latex so this problem might have been there before but I could find or understand the solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to replace `@Article` by `@article` (small `a`). Or delete the `aux` file.

Comment: You have to `\usepackage{harvard}` (before `\usepackage{hyperref}`). Remove `\usepackage{cite}`.

Comment: @Sigur - As far as BibTeX is concerned, `@article` and `@Article` are equally good -- capitalization does not matter for the spelling of the names of entry types and fields.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have

```
\usepackage{harvard}
```

instead of `\usepackage{cite}`; but it should be moved *before* `\usepackage{hyperref}`:

```
\usepackage{harvard}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% other settings

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\hyphenation{Sil-ben-trenn-ung}
```

Answer (score 2):

The advice that @egreg provides is good: Do *not* load the `cite` package if you want to use the `agsm` bibliography style. The `cite` package is meant to be used with numerical citation styles, whereas `agsm` is one of the style files distributed with the `harvard` citation management package and is meant to create authoryear-style citation call-outs.

Since you're also loading the `hyperref` package, I assume you would also like the citation callouts to be made into hyperlinks to the corresponding formatted entries in the bibliography. If that's indeed one of your objectives, you should *not* load the `harvard` package. Instead, load the `har2nat` and `natbib` packages. (As the package's name suggests, its purpose of the `har2nat` package is to "translate" citation macros of the `harvard` package into equivalent commands provided by the `natbib` package.) With `har2nat` and `natbib` loaded, citation callouts will automatically be made into hyperlinks -- something that won't happen if you load the `harvard` package.

For more information on this subject see, e.g., the posting [Why do hyperref and harvard not work together properly?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34258/5001)