# How to typeset - - with lstlisting package? 

Tags: listings, punctuation

Consider this small example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings} %for listings of the source code

\begin{document}

\lstset{language=sh}
\begin{lstlisting}
--   <-- Works!
a--b <-- Does not work!
-{}- <-- Won't help!
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

How to force `lstlisting` to typeset `--` instead of a long dash always? Also, how to increase distance between two consecutive dashes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the option `literate` to modify the output:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings} %for listings of the source code

\begin{document}

\lstset{language=sh,literate={--}{{-{}-}}1}
\begin{lstlisting}
--   <-- Works!
a--b <-- Does not work!
-{}- <-- Won't help!
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Furthermore you shouldn't use the option `utf8x`. An explanation can be found in the question [utf8x vs. utf8 (inputenc)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13067/utf8x-vs-utf8-inputenc)

Comment: Since the question also asks for "how to increase distance between two consecutive dashes?", the distance `\,` between `-\,-` as it was used before the last edit is correct.

Answer (score 9):

use

```
\lstset{language=sh,basicstyle=\ttfamily}
```

and if you want to use bold chracters than use a font like Bera Mono or Luxi Mono!

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scaled=0.83]{beramono}
\usepackage{listings} %for listings of the source code
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}
\begin{document}

\lstset{language=sh}
\begin{lstlisting}
--    # Works!
a--b  # Works
if else fi # Keywords work too! 
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are right, but CM typewriter does not have bold or italic variants - see my answer

Comment: sure and Courier is a "really not nice looking font ..."

Comment: Agreed, Courier is not nice.  Bera Mono is better - especially for presentation slides, where it can be combined with Bera Sans for body text and Arev for math - my favorite sans combinations

Comment: txfonts has a very nice typewriter font with italic, bold, and bold italic. (see also [newtxtt](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/newtxtt))

Answer (score 3):

First, if you use long dashes for options, then this works:

```
a --b
```

Second, the choice of propotional fonts for listings is ugly.  Unfortunately, CM typewriter does not have bold or italic variants, so just setting `\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}` is not what you want.  I prefer courier, which gives more satisfactory results:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{listings} %for listings of the source code
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}
\begin{document}

\lstset{language=sh}
\begin{lstlisting}
--    # Works!
a--b  # Works
if else fi # Keywords work too! 
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: txfonts provides very nice typewriter font. (nowadays `newtxtt` may be preferred)