# Using ligatures as Unicode

Tags: unicode, ligatures

I use TeX Live. See my example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
Check ligatures: ﬁrst % here I have ligature for "fi"
\end{document}
```

I have Unicode symbol here: `ﬁ`. When I compile the above LaTeX file I get:

```
! Package ucs Error: Unknown Unicode character 64257 = U+FB01
```

Then I apply the LaTeX system recommendation and compile the following file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{FB01}{ﬁ}% Here I defined a Unicode ligature
\begin{document}
Check ligatures: ﬁrst
\end{document}
```

But when I compile this LaTeX file I get:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   F
l.4 \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{FB01}{ﬁ}
```

So my question is: How can I input ligatures in a LaTeX file using just the ligature's Unicode symbol?

Comment: I'm wondering what you want to achieve as it is seems you are trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: Why do you think I solve wrong problem?

Comment: Using Unicode ligature glyphs does not make much sense with TeX since it will naturally do the ligaturing for you.

Comment: @KhaledHosny : you can have some Unicode ligature appearing in your TeX file through a cut'n paste operation. I remember having had some similar problems and I guess it is a legitimate possibility, even if not optimal.

Comment: I strongly recommend to use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX for this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two problems with the code:

1. [Use `[utf8]` instead of `[utf8x]`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13067/utf8x-vs-utf8-inputenc)
2. The second parameter of `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` is what the character will be replaced *with*, so it's meaningless to put the character there again. Replace it with what you reallly need (`f` and `i` will be joined in a ligature by TeX, as usual):
   `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{FB01}{fi}`

After these changes the code will work as desired.