# How can I use math inside a label in Description in a beamer doc?

Tags: math-mode, beamer, description

I'm describing regular expressions, and I would like to have items like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{default}

\mode<presentation>
{
 \usetheme{Warsaw}
 \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[vertical shading][bottom=white!10,top=blue!10]
 \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled=.80]{helvet}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]   

\begin{document}
\section{Search}
\subsection{Regular Exp}
 \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{\texttt{Regular Expressions} Operators}{Powerfull}
  \texttt{Regular Expressions} (\texttt{RE}) are good:
  \begin{description}
   \item[\textasciicircum]  Matches the beginning of the line
   \item[\textbackslash] Escape character
   \item[[]] Group characters
   \item[\textbackslash( \textbackslash)] Hell
   \item[$\textbackslash< \textbackslash> $] Hey.
%   \item[{$[:\mathtt{upper}:]$}] Same as $[A-Z]$.
  \end{description}
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

But some of them seem not to work. Some variants I've tried (with `]` outside math) gave me half of the item in the correct font/color, and the last char `]` in black as if it was normal text.

Please, how can I get this done?

--
Edited: minimal working example added.

Comment: The third and the fourth don't work because inner brackets need to be protected: `\item[{$[:\mathtt{upper}]$}]`. In other words, use braces `{...}` around optional arguments containing brackets `[...]`. However you don't need math mode.

Comment: Thanks @egreg, but still nothing. I've tried your suggestion like `\item[{$[:\mathtt{upper}:]$}] ha!`, but I got `<blue>[:upper:<\blue> <black>] ha!]<\black>`. Very strange, isn't it?

Comment: What do the `<blue>` and `<black>` tags stand for?

Comment: Nothing, just to tell you that the compiled text color should be blue for the label, and black only for ha!. But it is mixed in such way.

Comment: @egreg, sorry! I forgot to tell maybe a very important option: `\documentclass[10pt,hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}`

Comment: Please, show a complete minimal example.

Comment: I think I know your problem. You system isn't up to date.

Comment: Hi @MarcoDaniel. Please, can you be more specific? Is there a command to see versions? What version I should be seing? I'm using Debian squeeze stable, KDE and Kile. I'm curious about it. Thanks!

Comment: @DrBeco: Your example works fine for me. Please add the command `\listfiles` before `\documentclass` and in the log-file you will see all packages with version. I am using ubuntu with TeX Live 2011. I suppose you are using TeX Live 2009.

Comment: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian) entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24> Babel <v3.8l> beamer 2007/03/11 cvs version 3.07 (rcs-revision 1.70) MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02). pgfsys.sty 2008/02/07 v2.00 (rcs-revision 1.31) geometry.sty 2008/12/21 v4.2 amsmath.sty 2000/07/18 v2.13 inputenc.sty 2008/03/30 v1.1d utf8x.def 2004/10/17 ucs.sty 2004/10/17 portuges.ldf 2008/03/18 v1.2q t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g helvet.sty 2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a (WaS) bm.sty 2004/02/26 v1.1c nameref.sty    2007/05/29 v2.31 refcount.sty 2008/08/11 v3.1

Comment: @DrBeco: Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get what's expected with

```
\begin{description}
\item[\textasciicircum]  Matches the beginning of the line
\item[\textbackslash] Escape character
\item[{[]}] Group characters
\item[\textbackslash( \textbackslash)] Hell
\item[$\textbackslash< \textbackslash> $] Hey.
\item[{$[:\mathtt{upper}:]$}] Same as $[A-Z]$.
\end{description}
```

However, math mode is not necessary (and even wrong) in items number 5 and 6. Notice also the braces in the fourth item.

Here's how I would input the description list:

```
\begin{description}
\item[\texttt{\textasciicircum}]  Matches the beginning of the line
\item[\texttt{\textbackslash}] Escape character
\item[\texttt{[]}] Group characters
\item[\texttt{\textbackslash( \textbackslash)}] Hell
\item[\texttt{\textbackslash< \textbackslash>}] Hey.
\item[\texttt{[:upper:]}] Same as \texttt{[A-Z]}.
\end{description}
```

which will use typewriter type for the regular expression samples.

If all your description labels in a frame are to be typeset in typewriter type, then Marco Daniel's suggestion is good, but brackets must be hidden:

```
\setbeamerfont{description item}{family=\ttfamily} % this will hold until \end{frame}
\begin{description}
\item[\textasciicircum]  Matches the beginning of the line
\item[\textbackslash] Escape character
\item[{[]}] Group characters
\item[\textbackslash( \textbackslash)] Hell
\item[\textbackslash< \textbackslash>] Hey.
\item[{[:upper:]}] Same as \texttt{[A-Z]}.
\end{description}
```

Comment: 0 errors, 0 warnings, 0 badboxes. Thanks! Much appreciated.

Comment: @DrBeco: In beamer you should use `\setbeamerfont{description item}{family=\ttfamily}` instead of formating every label.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I think I do need to format every label. I tried `\setbeamerfont` and then `\item[[:upper:]]` would not work again: it move the last `]` outside the blue label and make it black font. I think `\texttt{}` is kind of "protecting" the label.

Comment: @egreg: Why do you refer `Mico` ;-(?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Oh, sorry!

Comment: @egreg: No problem ;-)

Answer (score 4):

**Update answer**

In the comments above it turned out that the @DrBeco uses TeX Live 2009. I suppose it was installed by the default repository of the unix system. However this version isn't up to date. I really recommend to install TeX Live 2011. In this way you can use the update manager [tlmgr](http://tug.org/texlive/tlmgr.html) to get the newest version of nearly every package. If you are using [TeX Live 2011](http://www.tug.org/texlive/) your example will work well.

I want to provide another hint. Don't use `utf8x`. Some explanation can be found here:

- [utf8x vs. utf8 (inputenc)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13067/utf8x-vs-utf8-inputenc)

**Original answer**

Why do you use commands like `\textasciicircum` or `\textbackslash` in math mode? The first part of the command indicates text not math.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \begin{description}
   \item[\textasciicircum] Matches the beginning of the line
   \item[\textbackslash] Escape character
   \item[{[]}] Group characters
   \item[\textbackslash( \textbackslash) ] Save to a buffer
   \item[{$[:\mathtt{upper}:]$}] Same as $[A-Z]$.
  \end{description}
\end{document}
```

The same result with `beamer`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\setbeamerfont{description item}{family=\ttfamily}
  \begin{description}
   \item[\textasciicircum]  Matches the beginning of the line
   \item[\textbackslash] Escape character
   \item[{[]}] Group characters
   \item[\textbackslash( \textbackslash) ] Save to a buffer
   \item[{$[:\mathtt{upper}:]$}] Same as $[A-Z]$.
  \end{description}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it is not working. @egreg gave the suggestion of `\item[{$[:\mathtt{upper}:]$}] Same as $[A-Z]$.`, but now it did not compile. It says there is an extra `}`. Another one according to you, how would you write: `\item[$\textbackslash< \textbackslash>$]`, please? Thanks.

Comment: @egreg: Does the example work for you? I have no problems

Comment: Wow! SORRY! I forgot to tell maybe a very important option: `\documentclass[10pt,hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}`

Comment: @DrBeco: No problems with beamer.

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't work here. Did you try with babel? Anyway, thanks, the \texttt{} solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks! I just changed to `utf8` and it compiled smoothly.

Comment: @DrBeco: In my opinion you should install TeX Live 2011 ;-)

Comment: @Mico ;) I'd love to, but I don't get out of the stable packages. It's a long-term-linux-user-precaution\ldots

Comment: @DrBeco: I am also a Linux user ;-) But most of the solutions will not work ;-)

Comment: Then follow my advice, my friend: I'd rather have a system that doesn't work in a know manner than have a system that doesn't work in an unknown manner.

Comment: @DrBeco: That's my new signature ;-)

Comment: LOL!!!!!!!!!!!!