# Do you need to write `` for quotation marks?

Tags: quotation

My understanding was always that, to write quotation marks in Latex, one should write ` and ' (instead of ‘ and ’). Recently, however, I pasted ‘ and ’ into Overleaf (from Microsoft Word) and could not see any discernible difference.

**Question:** Does Overleaf automatically convert Word quotation marks into ` and '? Is there any reason for me to convert them?

Comment: you can use "real" quotes if it is easier to input for you. Both input methods work.

Comment: I usually use straight "typewriter" quotes and have `csquotes` set them according to language and preferences. Using proper quotation marks directly works, too, of course.

Comment: [unicode - Fix all quotes in a document (pasted from another) - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66083/fix-all-quotes-in-a-document-pasted-from-another) and [symbols - What is the best way to use quotation mark glyphs? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/531/what-is-the-best-way-to-use-quotation-mark-glyphs) confirms that using smart quote in input source code is "supported", but I've no idea where it's documented or if it's "official".

Comment: As far as LaTeX is concerned, it's really just another Unicode character (which, unlike some others, have glyphs in practically all recent fonts. U+201C LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK, U+201D RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK and U+201E DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK should cover just about all variations.

Comment: Probably your "understanding" dates back to an earlier time. (pdf)latex didn't always support `‘` and `’` without loading additional packages, but that changed some time back; I'm not sure of the exact date.

Comment: Probably your "understanding" dates back to an earlier time. (pdf)latex didn't always support `‘` and `’` without loading additional packages, but that changed some time back; I'm not sure of the exact date.

Comment: OK thanks for all the comments!