# Enable letters with diaeresis

Tags: babel, accents, characters

My document is in in dutch and there are quite a few letters with diaeresis in it. I have this on top of my document:

```
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
```

I thought this would fix the language-problem but every letter with a diaeresis in it is left out. Any ideas how to enable those? It's mostly ï's and ë's.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`babel` doesn't allow you to input foreign characters (foreign to English) directly; it simply loads the appropriate hyphenation patterns and translates some predefined names (and possibly defines some shorthands).

You need to load the [`inputenc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/inputenc) package with an appropriate package option (typically, the `utf8` option) in order to directly typeset such characters (check that the chosen option matches the encoding for your editor); another package that you surely will want to load is `fontenc` with `Cork` encoding.

Without `inputenc` you can still produce the dieresis by using `\"`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}

\begin{document}

\"A\"E\"I\"O\"U\"a\"e\"i\"o\"u

ÄËÏÖÜäëïöü


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Same as before, but with a note about character encodings.

If you choose to stick with the UTF-8 encoding, you're on a good way, but read [this discussion about utf8 vs. utf8x](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13067/utf8x-vs-utf8-inputenc) for better results.

If you prefer to type your characters in the Windows manner (that is, ISO-8858-1 or latin1 or CP1252), you'll need to insert something like `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}`, which is fine except for some special characters and ligatures like œ (I mean `\oe`). Beware with this : typing œ in your source files could be a source of confusion, since the ISO-8859-15 and CP1252 encodings are (partially) incompatible. After some testing, you could perhaps use `\usepackage[cp1252]{inputenc}`.

Comment: Actually, latin1 and cp1252 are different encodings. In Windows, use cp1252.