# Problem with ẽ tilde and UTF8

Tags: unicode, font-encodings, tilde

I have a problem with the following character

> ẽ: e with tilde

I am using UTF-8 encoding and I get the following error

`! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:ẽ not set up for use with LaTeX.`

I am aware of this solution: `\~e` but the problem is that the `ẽ` that concerns me is the name of an author that is inside a bibtex that is automatically generated by mendeley...

I could, however, modify it in mendeley and cahnge `ẽ` for `\~e`, but is not a very elegant solution...

Anyway, I can let go this and simply replace it for `e` if there is no solution. I am just curious as to why UTF-8 does not handle this? I thougth UTF-8 handled every possible character.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

This does not work:  ẽ

This works: \~e

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe you could have a look at [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34604/entering-unicode-characters-in-latex). The provided solution is to use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, and if this is not sufficient, which seems to be your case, to use `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` to replace a unicode character with a latex sequence

Comment: You could use `utf8x`, but [avoid](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13067/utf8x-vs-utf8-inputenc) it. Better use XeTeX. It worse being used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The range of Unicode characters is quite large. Therefore `utf8.def` limits itself to the characters that can be displayed using one of the font encodings that are loaded. The disadvantage that some characters, that can be constructed via accents can slip through. Therefore `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` allows to add these characters:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{1eBC}{\~E}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{1EBD}{\~e}
```

Addition (see egreg's comment):

Package `newunicodechar` provides `\newunicodechar` that declares the character without specifying its explicit code number:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{Ẽ}{\~E}
\newunicodechar{ẽ}{\~e}
```

Also version 1.3 of package [`selinput`](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/71873949/tex/selinput-1.3.pdf) (updated on CTAN with next bundle release, `.dtx` is attached and the `.sty` file extracted by running plain `tex` on the `.dtx` file)
provides this feature via `\DeclareInputUnicodeChar`. The following example adds a key value interface for setting the Unicode characters, making it easier to type, if lots of additional Unicode character declarations are needed:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{selinput}[2012/09/29]
\usepackage{kvsetkeys}
\makeatletter
\kv@parse{
  Ẽ=\~E,
  ẽ=\~e,
}\DeclareInputUnicodeChar
\makeatother
```

The new version 1.12 of [`inputenx`](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/71873949/tex/inputenx-1.12.pdf) will add support for these characters by

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% or inputenx
\input{ix-utf8enc.dfu}% 2012/11/12 or later needed
```

Comment: A way that avoids looking for the Unicode point is to use `newunicodechar`: `\usepackage{newunicodechar}` and then `\newunicodechar{ẽ}{\~e}`.

Comment: Is there any pros and cons if we compare these two solutions? Which one is better? newunicodechar or DeclareUnicodeCharacter?

Comment: I've just uploaded version 1.1 of newunicodechar that sports compatibility with `inputenx`

Comment: @FelipeAguirre The two are equivalent; with `\newunicodechar` you don't need to know the Unicode point of the character you want to give a meaning to.

Comment: "One of the font encodings that are loaded" I think either this is wrong, or you mean "will be loaded when `\begin{document}` is executed"? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13067/utf8x-vs-utf8-inputenc/34046#comment476003_34046

Comment: @user202729 Usually fonts are used *after* `\begin{document}`. Thus the precise location of the supported font encoding is more or less an implementation detail: The file `utf8.def` processes the known font encodings in `\cdp@list` and extends macro `\DeclareFontEncoding` to catch future font encodings.