# Getting Hebrew Support Working with Pandoc

Tags: xetex, pandoc, hebrew

Does anyone know why `pandoc`, with the `xelatex` engine might not generate hebrew characters while directly calling `xelatex` does?

That is, I have a simple `.tex` file with some hebrew in it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}{New Peninim MT}
\begin{document}
\title{שלום עולם}
\author{שלום עולם}
\maketitle

שלום עולם

\end{document}
```

If I feed this to `xelatex`

```
$ xelatex simple.tex
```

I get a PDF file will hebrew characters. Yay!

However, if I feed the same document to `pandoc`, specifying the `--latex-engine=xelatex` engine.

```
$ pandoc --latex-engine=xelatex simple.tex -o test.pdf
```

I get a PDF with no rendered hebrew characters.  Does anyone know why this happens, and how I might fix it?  I assume pandoc is calling `xelatex` in the background -- is there a way to view which options/arguments/flags its invoking it with, or to *clearout* those options?

Also -- My ultimate goal is to convert an HTML document with some hebrew characters into a PDF file with `pandoc` and I run into similar problems when I have a file (`simple.html`) like

```
<h1>שלום עולם</h1>
```

and then attempt to convert it

```
pandoc --latex-engine=xelatex simple.html -o test.pdf
```

The above also produces a hebrew-less file.

So, I'm using `pandoc` to convert to the `simple.tex` file as a debugging technique, not because I'm actually moving from `tex` to PDF.  I know I can invoke `xelatex` directly and get this to work, but for complicated reasons I'd like this working with `pandoc`.  I'd also like to understand how `pandoc` is actually interacting with LaTeX.  So bonus points for those sorts of answers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandoc can work with unicode hebrew text, if the font configuration is right (the readers are omitting font info since they are not represented in pandoc's AST).

*1. Configure fonts in pandoc explicitly*

So you have to tell pandoc explicitly, which font to use: `-V mainfont:"Times New Roman"` 
And if you want to set the text direction to right-to-left you can use: `-V dir:rtl`

Which yields:

```
pandoc --latex-engine=xelatex \
        -V mainfont:"Times New Roman" \
        -V dir:rtl \
simple.tex -o test.pdf
```

[image]

```
pandoc --latex-engine=xelatex \
        -V mainfont:"Times New Roman" \
        -V dir:rtl \
simple.html -o test.pdf
```

[image]

*2. Add the font configuration to the template:*

You need a new file `include.tex`:

```
% include.tex
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}{New Peninim MT}
```

also tell pandoc to use hebrew as main language: `-V lang:he`

Which yields:

```
pandoc --latex-engine=xelatex \
        -V lang:he \
        -H include.tex \
simple.tex -o test.pdf
```

[image]

```
pandoc --latex-engine=xelatex   
        -V lang:he \
        -H include.tex \
simple.html -o test.pdf
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Your `pandoc` command expects a `.html` file as input*. It is thus normal that is does not work when you use a `.tex` file as input.

Indeed pandoc principle is the following:

```
.html-file -->[html-to-latex]--> .tex-file -->[(xe)latex compiling]--> .pdf-file
              |___________________________________________________|
                               pandoc, as a black-box
```

For example the following html document:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Lorem</h1>
    Ipsum dolor sit amet
  </body>
</html>
```

would be converted into such a tex document (this is a dummy example, just to explain the principle. I'm not sure the `-->[html-to-latex]-->` would give *exactly* the same output):

```
\documentclass{article}
   %<automatically loaded packages>
   \title{My title}
\begin{document}
   \section{Lorem}
   Ipsum dolor sit amet
\end{document}
```

Pandoc might include some packages in the preable (e.g. `inputenc`, etc.) but it is not smart enough to know that you want some specific package or settings (in your case `\setmainlanguage{hebrew}`, `\setmainfont{Times New Roman}`, and `\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}{New Peninim MT}`). You should thus check `pandoc`'s documentation to know how to include these settings in the preamble of your document.

---

<sup>* Well, it's a bit over-simplified, as `pandoc` as a much broader range of application. This simplification is for explanation purpose only.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your attention.  However -- *Your pandoc command expects a `.html` file as input*  -- I'm not sure this is 100% correct.  If you look at the pandoc demo page (http://pandoc.org/demos.html) it seems like pandoc's a program for converting between various text formats.  HTML to [Something Else] might be the most common case, but [tex] to [pdf] seems equally valid.  Also, at the heart of my questions is how is pandoc and xelatex interact.  I get the basic pipeline -- what I'm after is how pandoc is using xelatex, and how customizable it is.

Comment: @AlanStorm You're right: `pandoc` is basically used to convert a *x*-file into a *y*-file (e.g. I use it to transform a `.tex` file into a `.doc` one). Your question thus focus on "how to customize the `html-to-latex` function in `pandoc`". You can have a look at the [documentation](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.pdf) (§ Variables for LaTeX) but I'm not sure it's enough to solve your question. It might become a bit out-of-scope for this site, though.

Comment: @AlanStorm (In my case, I defined a `.doc` template that is given as parameter when running `pandoc`. Something similar might be possible with `.tex` boilerplates, but I don't know how to do it.)

Comment: Thanks @ebo -- i get that its on the fringes of scope for this site, but as it does involved xelatex I'm hoping it falls inside the ring of acceptable question.  Not your job to go above and beyond though, and thank you for your help both today and last night!