# English document with hebrew pages

Tags: page-numbering, babel, languages, hebrew

I have just wrote my a large paper in English. Now, I need to write from the end of the paper few pages in Hebrew (it is from the end of the paper since it is written from right to left).

The whole English paper is numbered with Arabic page numbering. Now I need to do 2 things:

1) I need the Hebrew pages to start numbering in the opposite direction in Rome letters.

2) How do I make a document with both Hebrew and English languages?

For example, the paper numbering should be as follows:

1...2...3...4......III..II..I

I tried to use:

```
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hebrew,english]{babel}

However I got Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'ucs'.
```

Note: I also use biblatex package and from what I understand they both does not work together.

Thank you.

Comment: While posting your query, please do add a Minimal Working Example, you are more likely to get answers when you do!

Comment: As for working in both Hebrew and English, you should take a look at this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202194/babel-for-hebrew?rq=1 . Hope this helps solve a part of your query.

Comment: Sounds like you're finishing up your thesis (congratulations!). Check out this template http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/graduate/etc/thesis-template/index.html it consists of using babel and flipping the pages as well as numbering the pages in the way you described

Comment: Even better than my last link is this one: https://github.com/eyalroz/technion-iit-thesis, up to date and working

Comment: You can probably create two different documents and merge PDFs.