# KOMA classes and Hebrew script with Polyglossia

Tags: xetex, koma-script, polyglossia, hebrew, scrartcl

I am trying to type a text with both Hebrew and English. Following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/202196/49039), I was trying to use `polyglossia` together with a Hebrew Font I downloaded from [OpenSiddur](https://opensiddur.org/help/fonts/).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}{Shlomo semiStam}


\begin{document}
\title{שלום עולם}
\author{שלום עולם}
\maketitle
העיר מקודשת ליהדות, לנצרות ולאסלאם, והיוותה מרכז חיי העם היהודי בימי
קדם ומושא געגועיו בזמן שהייתו בגלות. משום מרכזיותה בעולמם של המאמינים,
הייתה העיר מוקד למלחמות וסכסוכים הנמשכים עד עצם היום הזה. מאז סוף המאה
ה-19 התפתחו סביב העיר העתיקה שכונות העיר החדשה, המהוות כיום את רובה
המוחלט של העיר. במרכזה של ירושלים השלמה עומד הר הבית, שמפריד בין מערב
ירושלים למזרח ירושלים.

\end{document}
```

Using the `article` class together with XeLaTeX, the document compiles without any problem, but I would prefer to use the KOMA class `scrartcl`.

I get

```
! Package polyglossia Error:
The current roman font does not contain the Hebrew script!

(polyglossia) Please define \hebrewfont with \newfontfamily.
```

even though I defined a Hebrew font. I tried interchanging the order of package and language loading, but this didn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The KOMA classes use more font families. In you case a \sffamily. You need to setup a font for it too, and while you are on it, do it also for \ttfamily (the error message is quite misleading, it would be much better it would actually mention the family):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}{Arial}   %chose a suitable font ...
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfontsf}{Arial} %\sffamily 
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfonttt}{Arial} % \ttfamily

\begin{document}
\title{שלום עולם}
\author{שלום עולם}
\maketitle
העיר מקודשת ליהדות, לנצרות ולאסלאם, והיוותה מרכז חיי העם היהודי בימי
קדם ומושא געגועיו בזמן שהייתו בגלות. משום מרכזיותה בעולמם של המאמינים,
הייתה העיר מוקד למלחמות וסכסוכים הנמשכים עד עצם היום הזה. מאז סוף המאה
ה-19 התפתחו סביב העיר העתיקה שכונות העיר החדשה, המהוות כיום את רובה
המוחלט של העיר. במרכזה של ירושלים השלמה עומד הר הבית, שמפריד בין מערב
ירושלים למזרח ירושלים.

\ttfamily שלום עולם
\end{document}
```