# A bug in in babel-hebrew?

Tags: pdftex, babel, hebrew

As the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/202248/264024) state, after installing [culmus-latex](http://www.guyrutenberg.com/culmus-latex/), the following document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,hebrew]{babel}
\begin{document} 
שלום \L{World}!
\end{document}
```

compiles with pdflatex with no errors. After changing the document class to `extarticle`, the following error occurs: `Command \l@chapter undefined. \fi}}}}`. The error comes from the file `rlbabel.def`. In this file there is the following code (starting at line 401):

```
\@ifclassloaded{letter}{}{%
\@ifclassloaded{slides}{}{%
  \@ifclassloaded{article}{}{%
    \renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
      \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
      \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
      \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
      \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
      \begingroup
         \parindent \z@ \if@rl\leftskip\else\rightskip\fi \@pnumwidth
         \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
         \leavevmode \bfseries
         \advance\if@rl\rightskip\else\leftskip\fi\@tempdima
         \hskip -\if@rl\rightskip\else\leftskip\fi
         #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss#2}\par
         \penalty\@highpenalty
      \endgroup
      \fi}}}}
```

It seems that babel-hebrew checks if the document class is one of letter, slides or article, if so it does nothing, else it changes the definition of `\l@chapter`.

Wouldn't it make more sense to check if the command `\l@chapter` exists and by that determine if it should be changed? if so, who should i contact about the subject?

From [this page](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel-hebrew) it looks like there is no active maintainer to babel-hebrew, and the documentation was last updated in 2013.

Comment: Maybe try to contact the active maintainer Arthur Rosendahl. He has other packages that were updated just recently.

Comment: See https://www.ctan.org/author/reutenauer

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, thank you, probably because it is late i missed the fact that there is an active maintainer...