# Missing Hebrew letters in beamer presentation

Tags: beamer

I'm trying to make a beamer presentation with overleaf, however Hebrew letters are missing from the output:

[image]

```
\documentclass[
    11pt, % Set the default font size, options include: 8pt, 9pt, 10pt, 11pt, 12pt, 14pt, 17pt, 20pt
    %t, % Uncomment to vertically align all slide content to the top of the slide, rather than the default centered
    %aspectratio=169, % Uncomment to set the aspect ratio to a 16:9 ratio which matches the aspect ratio of 1080p and 4K screens and projectors
]{beamer}

\graphicspath{{Images/}{./}} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usefonttheme{default}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[default]{opensans} 
\useinnertheme{circles}
\usepackage[hebrew,english]{babel}
\selectlanguage{hebrew}
\title{פרויקט}
\subtitle{שם }
\author[שם המגיש]{שם המגיש}
\institute{אוניברסיטה}
\date[\today]{תורת החרטוטיות \\ \today}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

P.S This is my compiler settings:

[image]

Comment: What is you compiler setting (in Overleaf click the Menu button in the top left and then in the middle the Compiler section)?

Comment: Marijn, edited.

Comment: In any case, the current setup with the `palatino` and `opensans` packages is unlikely to work, you can read https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202194/babel-for-hebrew to find a number of approaches for Hebrew.

Comment: Ah, I am not sure i know how to do it, would you mind merging it into my code?

Comment: After changing the compiler to LuaLaTeX you can use the following (slightly modified from the linked question): `\usetheme{Madrid}
\usefonttheme{default}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=sectioning.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=he, onchar=fonts ids]{hebrew}

\babelfont{rm}{DejaVu Serif}
\babelfont{sf}{DejaVu Sans}
\babelfont{tt}{DejaVu Sans Mono}`

Comment: Also I'm wondering now what you plan to say on the theory of cartography :)

Comment: Marijn, fantastic! It works! Please consider posting it as an answer so i could accept it.

Comment: If it works then that means it is a duplicate, I only simplified the code a bit and changed the font names. I will vote to close.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142033/discussion-between-linuxninja-and-marijn).