# Hebrew (right to left) title in biblatex

Tags: right-to-left

Is there a way to use Hebrew in the title field of bibliography database, so it might be displayed properly when the bibliography is generated by biblatex? What happens is: the Hebrew text appears correctly (utf8 encoding) but the last world becomes the first.

To give you some context: The rest of the bibliographic citation has latin characters as I'm writing in Italian, but with some Hebrew in the text and in the bibliography.

```
\documentclass{article}[9pt]
\begin{filecontents*}{Midrash.bib}
@book{frenkelYvnymBvlmvHrvkhny1981a, 
title = {עיונים בעולמו הרוחני של ספור האגדה.}, 
author = {Frenḳel, Yonah.}, 
date = {1981}, 
publisher = {{Hakibuts Hame'uḥad}}, 
location = {{Tel-Aviv}}, 
langid = {hebrew} 
} 
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{reledmac} 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\usepackage{wrapfig} 
\setdefaultlanguage{italian} 
\setotherlanguage{hebrew} 
\setmainfont{Times New Roman} 
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad3,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,eprint=false]{biblatex}
\bibliography{Midrash.bib} 
\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph} 
\begin{document} 
see \cite{frenkelYvnymBvlmvHrvkhny1981a} 
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

The result is shown in the image below:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using `babel`? With pdfTeX, XeTeX, LuaTeX?

Comment: \usepackage{polyglossia}


\setdefaultlanguage{italian}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
 \newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}{New Peninim MT}

Comment: And I'm compiling with xelatex, biber

Comment: And this is the bibliographic entry:

Comment: @book{frenkelYvnymBvlmvHrvkhny1981a,
  title = {עיונים בעולמו הרוחני של ספור האגדה.},
  author = {Frenḳel, Yonah.},
  date = {1981},
  publisher = {{Hakibuts Hame'uḥad}},
  location = {{Tel-Aviv}},
  langid = {hebrew}
}

Comment: Not an answer, but I think you misspelled סיפור in your title.

Comment: Good point! I imported automatically from WorldCat...

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you can edit your question to include a complete minimal document that shows the problem (it should run from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` and you can add your bib file as a separate code block (use the `{}` button to show your code as code.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to show the code as code

Comment: \documentclass{article}[9pt]

\usepackage{reledmac}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\setdefaultlanguage{italian}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
 \newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}{New Peninim MT}


\usepackage[style=verbose-trad3, doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,eprint=false]{biblatex}

\bibliography{Midrash.bib}

\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}







\begin{document}

see \cite{frenkelYvnymBvlmvHrvkhny1981a}

\printbibliography

\end{document}

Comment: It is not a solution, but you set hebrew as the main language and the text will be right order. I've tried explicitly using ```\texthebrew{...}``` or ```\begin{hebrew}...\end{hebrew}```to enter the bibliography title, but it did not work.

Comment: Thanks! Cannot set Hebrew as main language as the main text is left to right. There are Hebrew quotations in the text using  \begin{hebrew}...\end{hebrew} which works just fine to isolate to right to left chunks... I guess I will just transliterate the Hebrew titles in the bibliography.

Comment: @Haim What, you can’t cite only palindromes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that you have to tell `polyglossia` what font to use for each language, and when you are using each language.

[image: hebrew bib]

Blue is FreeSerif font set as `\hebrewfont`.

By the time `biblatex`/`biber` reads the .bib file, the `polyglossia` command in the .bib file is already established, because `polyglossia` has been loaded before `biblatex`.

The dummy bib ref is just a random snippet from the Wikipedia article on the solar system.

MWE

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{article}[9pt]
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{Midrash.bib}
    @book{frenkelYvnymBvlmvHrvkhny1981a, 
        title = {\begin{hebrew}עיונים בעולמו הרוחני של סיפור האגדה\end{hebrew}.}, 
        author = {Frenḳel, Yonah.}, 
        date = {1981}, 
        publisher = {{Hakibuts Hame'uḥad}}, 
        location = {{Tel-Aviv}}, 
        langid = {hebrew} 
    } 
    @book{מ,
    title={\begin{hebrew}מערכת השמש\end{hebrew}},
    author={\begin{hebrew}נפטון\end{hebrew}},
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{reledmac} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\usepackage{wrapfig} 
\setdefaultlanguage{italian} 
\setotherlanguage{hebrew} 
\setmainfont{Times New Roman} 
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{FreeSerif}[Script=Hebrew,Color=blue]
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad3, doi=false,
isbn=false,
url=false,
eprint=false, 
backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Midrash.bib} 
\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph} 
\begin{document} 
    \section{אבגד -- without environment}
    \section{\begin{hebrew}אבגד \end{hebrew} -- with environment}
            \begin{hebrew}אבגד הוז חטיך כלםמ ןנסע ףפץצ קרשת\end{hebrew}
            
    See \cite{frenkelYvnymBvlmvHrvkhny1981a,מ} 
    \printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

I used `biblatex`'s `\addbibresource` command, as well.

---

**Addendum**

*Babel package*

Lualatex can identify scripts by using Unicode algorithms, so explicit markup is not generally needed. (Multiple runs of different scripts diving in and out of the main script, like the Latin texts in the Hebrew-version bibliography, *will* need markup, for a tidier presentation.)

For a comparison of intermingled languages (ignoring runs), using `babel` package compiled with lualatex to take advantage of this feature, with Italian as the main language:

[image: italian main]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}[9pt]
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
    @book{frenkelYvnymBvlmvHrvkhny1981a, 
        title = {עיונים בעולמו הרוחני של סיפור האגדה.}, 
        author = {Frenḳel, Yonah.}, 
        date = {1981}, 
        publisher = {{Hakibuts Hame'uḥad}}, 
        location = {{Tel-Aviv}}, 
        langid = {hebrew} 
    } 
    @book{מ,
    title={מערכת השמש},
    author={נפטון},
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{reledmac} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{wrapfig} 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage[italian,bidi=basic]{babel}%<--- main language 
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\babelfont{rm}{Noto Serif}
\babelfont{sf}{Noto Sans}
\babelfont{tt}{Noto Sans Mono}
\babelprovide[import, onchar=fonts ids]{hebrew}
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}[Color=blue]{LiberationSerif}

%\makeatletter%workaround to satisfy biblatex parms - not needed
%\newtoggle{blx@lang@captions@english}
%\makeatother

\usepackage[style=verbose-trad3, doi=false,
isbn=false,
url=false,
eprint=false, 
backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 

\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph} 
\begin{document} 
    \section{אבגד}
            אבגד הוז חטיך כלםמ ןנסע ףפץצ קרשת

The cat sat on the mat.

    \section{הוז}
            אבגד הוז the cat חטיך כלםמ ןנסע ףפץצ קרשת
 
            
See \cite{frenkelYvnymBvlmvHrvkhny1981a,מ} 
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

and with Hebrew as the main language:

[image: hebrew main]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}[9pt]
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
    @book{frenkelYvnymBvlmvHrvkhny1981a, 
        title = {עיונים בעולמו הרוחני של סיפור האגדה.}, 
        author = {Frenḳel, Yonah.}, 
        date = {1981}, 
        publisher = {{Hakibuts Hame'uḥad}}, 
        location = {{Tel-Aviv}}, 
        langid = {hebrew} 
    } 
    @book{מ,
    title={מערכת השמש},
    author={נפטון},
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{reledmac} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{wrapfig} 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel} 
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\babelfont{rm}{Noto Serif}
\babelfont{sf}{Noto Sans}
\babelfont{tt}{Noto Sans Mono}
\babelprovide[import, main, onchar=fonts ids]{hebrew}%<-- main language
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}[Color=blue]{LiberationSerif}

\makeatletter%workaround to satisfy biblatex parms
\newtoggle{blx@lang@captions@english}
\makeatother

\usepackage[style=verbose-trad3, doi=false,
isbn=false,
url=false,
eprint=false, 
backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 

\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph} 
\begin{document} 
    \section{אבגד}
            אבגד הוז חטיך כלםמ ןנסע ףפץצ קרשת

The cat sat on the mat.

    \section{הוז}
            אבגד הוז the cat חטיך כלםמ ןנסע ףפץצ קרשת
 
            
See \cite{frenkelYvnymBvlmvHrvkhny1981a,מ} 
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks it works.

Comment: Only 2 questions:

Comment: 1. It does not seem to work with XeLatex (tell me if I'm wrong) then I will have to investigate LuaLatex, which I do not use and do not know...; 2. It is a bit weird to have the \beginhebrew environment in my Zotero library with makes it unsuitable for other copy paste usages...

Comment: (1) `babel` package with lualatex can auto-detect the script(s), no need of environments; (2) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138992/help-getting-started-with-hebrew-in-babel/611604#611604 may help; (3) choosing a compiler is done simply via a drop-down list in TeXworks editor in TeXLive distribution (on Windows); how do you choose to run xelatex/lualatex/pdflatex/etc? (4) make sure all your packages and distribution are up-to-date;  (5) ask a separate question (linking back to this one) about running under a specific setup, version or package combination(s) - more eyes on it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications!