# Problem with Culmus on Windows

Tags: installing, languages, hebrew

I've been [here](http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/%7Esameti/tex/lyxhebrew.html) and followed all the instructions with the only exception that MikTex is installed only for one user and not for every user. At the end of everything Lyx works perfectly but when I compile tells me that "culmus.sty" cannot be found.

I therefore tried to reinstall Miktex for every users but it seems that it cannot install for every users (not sure why: the wizard setup gives a strange output with all possible options one can give to the wizard setups and then exits form the installation)

Does anybody know if I can solve this problem copying the culmus.sty in some directory?

Comment: You can create a new root and attach it in the MiKTeX console but do you really want to write Hebrew with pdflatex? Why don't you use lualatex?

Comment: thank you... could you expand a little your comment? Should I create a folder in the MikTex folder with "culmus.sty" in it?

Comment: see https://miktex.org/faq#collapse2069. But I really recommend to use an unicode engine like lualatex, the few times I tried culmus it was a pain (and due to missing fonts didn't always work).

Answer (score 2):

First, I recommend using modern fonts in a Unicode engine if you can, and legacy 8-bit fonts if you have to.

To get the Culmus fonts working in PDFLaTeX, you want to download [these `culmus-latex` files](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ivritex/files/culmus-latex/) into a local directory and add it as a root in MikTeX.  With TeX Live, you want to copy the folder to the directory given by `kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFLOCAL` (which is often `C:\texlive\texmf-local\`).

You then want to run, as whichever user installed TeX, the commands

```
texhash
updmap-sys --enable Map=culmus.map
```

The command `\usepackage{culmus}` should then work.  [Here are some test cases.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138992/help-getting-started-with-hebrew-in-babel/611604#611604)