# Problems with links at XeTeX

Tags: xetex, hyperref, paragraphs, links, hebrew

When I'm trying to make a link, and the links breaks for two lines or more, all the paragraph become the link, and the first word (at the MWE) is in the wrong place (at the end of the sentence....

Here is a MWE:

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.3.7 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[a4paper,english,hebrew,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},pdfborderstyle={},backref=false,colorlinks=true]
 {hyperref}
\hypersetup{
 linkcolor=blue}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Arial}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Arial}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Arial}
\AtBeginDocument{
\renewcommand\footnoterule{%
  \kern -3pt
  \hbox to \textwidth{\hfill\vrule height 0.4pt width .4\textwidth}
  \kern 2.6pt
}}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \def\labelitemi{\Pisymbol{psy}{183}}
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
אאא אאא אאאאא אאאא בבבבב בבבבבבב בבבבבבבב גגגגגגגג גגגגגג גג \LRE{\href{http://www.lyx.org}{הלינק הם המילים הללו רק}}
בבבב בבב גגגג גגגג גגגג דדדדד ההההה וווווווווו הההההוווו ווווו ההההההההההה
חחחחחחחחחח
\end{document}
```

As you can see this is the output:
[image: The Link in the blue]
Only the underline words are link (not all the paragraph).

And the underline word (with the red line) should be where is the green line:
[image: Wrong order of words]

Do you know how can I make it works fine? The the words will be at the right order and only the linked words will be linked? *(It's happens only at Hebrew, and not at English)*.

Thank you!

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem on overleaf... Is your installation up-to-date?

Comment: @koleygr - Yes, I update it (MikTeX) today.

Comment: use lualatex and babel. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/561139/2388.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, not working :-( Can you please show how I can put it at my MWE?

Comment: sorry but "not working" is not a sensible problem description. Apart from this I don't use lyx.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, sorry, I mean - It's not compiling. My MWE compiling at TeXworks (not LyX) so I wonder I can I put your solution at my MWE, not matter how I tried - it's not compiling...

Comment: well you will have to adapt your document if you want to use lualatex. Start with the example I linked to and if that compiles change one by one what you want to change.