# lgrxenc.def not nound

Tags: fonts, packages, compiling, greek

Yesterday I've finally reinstalled my TeXLive to the version of 2014. While compiling, I have the following error:

> fontec.sty Package fontenc Error: Encoding file `lgrxenc.def' not
>   found \ProcessOptions*

What can in mean and how do I fight it?

Comment: Do you mean `fontenc.sty`? As always we need a minimal example which is compilable and shows this error to us. Like this (for me) its just a guessing around.

Comment: the lgrx-package is obsolete and has been replaced by greek-fontenc. See the readme to learn how to adapt your documents: http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/ctan/obsolete/macros/latex/contrib/lgrx/README

Comment: Yes, well, I think I have found the answer to my problem. There was an old package in preamble that I've tried to use, so I've just got  rid of it. Sorry for a stupid question.

Comment: @user17040 No, it's not a stupid question. For a number of reasons, Greek encodings never reached an “official” status and a couple of years ago a special `LGRx` encoding was proposed that allowed direct UTF-8 input also for Greek. After this, the encoding was incorporated into Babel and in the “official” files, so `\usepackage[LGRx]{fontenc}` has become illegal. Perhaps, for ensuring back compatibility, such code should issue a warning instead of a weird error.

Comment: Many thanks for the replies. Now everything works properly everywhere.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a good question, because the issue can happen to other users.

For several years, the only practical way for inputting Greek was through a transliteration table (`a` for alpha, `b` for beta, `'a` for alpha with tonos and so on).

TeX Live 2012 included the `lgrx` package that allowed direct UTF-8 input of Greek, so that a UTF-8 document like

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[LGRx,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,english]{babel}
\begin{document}

The starting verse of the Iliad is
\begin{quotation}\greektext
Μῆνιν ἄειδε, θεά, Πηληιάδεω Ἀχιλῆος
\end{quotation}
and it's really great.

\end{document}
```

could be written. The `lgrx` package started to circulate some time before the release of TeX Live 2012 and, as said, it was included in it. However, starting from TeX Live 2013, the `lgrx` was incorporated in the `greek-fontenc` package, which is now standard, so just adding `greek` (or the polytonic version) to `babel` automatically load it.

Unfortunately, back compatibility wasn't taken into account, with the result that documents written in the interval between the releases of TeX Live 2012 and 2013 are now broken, in the sense that the error message

```
! Package fontenc Error: Encoding file `lgrxenc.def' not found.
(fontenc)                You might have misspelt the name of the encoding.
```

is issued, though just going past the error produces a valid document.

The `greek-fontenc` package *should* contain a file `lgrxenc.def` containing something like

```
\PackageWarningNoLine{fontenc}
  {Remember to remove `LGRx' from the options\MessageBreak
   to `fontenc' as it's not required any more}
\endinput
```

so that just a warning

```
Package fontenc Warning: Remember to remove `LGRx' from the options
(fontenc)                to `fontenc' as it's not required any more.
```

is issued when the above document is processed.

If you have documents containing the `LGRx` option to `fontenc`, you can save the “compatibility `lgrxenc.def`” file in your personal tree: for a GNU/Linux machine it would be

```
~/texmf/tex/latex/lgrx-compatibility/lgrxenc.def
```

(where `~` stands for your home directory). For MacTeX it should be

```
~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/lgrx-compatibility/lgrxenc.def
```

On Windows it should be

```
%USERPROFILE%\texmf\tex\latex\lgrx-compatibility\lgrxenc.def
```

(where `%USERPROFILE%` refers to the analog of the home directory).

Create the necessary directories, as they are not created during installation of TeX Live.

It might be a good idea to make a feature request to the maintainer of `greek-fontenc`.

Comment: Many thanks once again. This was really helpful for my other documents.

Answer (score 5):

You can make your life easier if you could switch to `xelatex` or `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,english]{babel}
\begin{document}

The starting verse of the Iliad is
\begin{quotation}
Μῆνιν ἄειδε, θεά, Πηληιάδεω Ἀχιλῆος
\end{quotation}
and it's really great.

\end{document}
```

There is no need for a special encoding.

[image]