# compiler complains about apacite

Tags: bibliographies, errors

I use the following packages in my document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,BCOR=10mm]{scrbook}
% Packages
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[icelandic, english]{babel}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\usepackage{enumerate,color}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[sort&compress,authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage[sf,normalsize]{subfigure}
\usepackage[format=plain,labelformat=simple,labelsep=colon]{caption}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{tabularx}
% Configurations
\graphicspath{{figs/}}
```

When I add

```
\usepackage{apacite}
```

I get a bunch of errors, starting with:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1203 \st@rtbibchapter
```

Note that apacite should be correctly included in my system as I use it without problems on another document.

Do you have any idea where is the problem?

Comment: As discussed at length in the [`apacite` manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/apacite), don't load `natbib` separately, instead use `apacite` with the `natbibapa` option like so: `\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}`.

Comment: likewise, as has been in the uk faq since 1994, don't use `t1enc` -- it's long been replaced by `fontenc`: see the [faq answer on t1enc](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=t1enc)

Comment: The use of **both** suggestions made the doc compile. Thanks a lot @PaulGessler and wasteofspace. I'm actually using an official template from my university, I had no idea of the purpose of those packages and recommendations. You saved me a lot of latex-research. I'd be glad to upvote/accept your answers if you provide one.

Comment: @wasteofspace see up, cannot tag multiple users in one comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`apacite` package documentation](http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/apacite):

> When you want to use `natbib` for citation and `apacite` for the reference list, you still need to load the LaTeX package `apacite.sty` (with `\usepackage`), because of the commands that are included in the BibTeX output. The best interoperability is obtained by loading `apacite` with the `natbibapa` option. There is then no need to load `natbib` explicitly, because `apacite` already does this.

So you should replace

```
\usepackage[sort&compress,authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{apacite}
```

with

```
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
```

From the [`t1enc` package page on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/t1enc):

> Ob­so­lete pack­age for ac­ti­vat­ing T1 font en­cod­ing. The re­place­ment [`fontenc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontenc) pack­age with (op­tional) ar­gu­ment `T1` does this task more sat­is­fac­to­rily.

So you should replace

```
\usepackage{t1enc}
```

with

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Other notes on your omnibus preamble:

1. I don't use `utf8` encoding in my source files often enough to provide a definitive answer on this point, but you may want to consider [`utf8x` vs. `utf8` (`inputenc`)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13067/utf8x-vs-utf8-inputenc) for a discussion of the relative merits of `utf8x`/`ucs` and `inputenc`.
2. [`subfigure` is deprecated](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfigure); use [`subfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig) or [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) instead.
3. `koma-script` (of which your class, `scrbook`, is a part) implements nearly all functionality from the `caption` package, so you should consider using the built-in class options instead of using `caption`.
4. `hyperref` should be loaded last, with only [a few exceptions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/21344).

Here's the complete code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,BCOR=10mm]{scrbook}
% Packages
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[icelandic, english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\usepackage{enumerate,color}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
%\usepackage[sort&compress,authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite} % use `natbibapa' option instead of `natbib` package
%\usepackage[sf,normalsize]{subfigure} % deprecated; use other means
%\usepackage[format=plain,labelformat=simple,labelsep=colon]{caption} % use class commands instead
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref} % moved to end of packages

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```