# compiler complains about apacite - Undefined control sequence. \st@rtbibchapter

Tags: bibliographies, errors

I use the following code in my document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                     
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}    

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

Adding the package

```
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
```

results in a bunch of errors starting with

```
Undefined control sequence. \st@rtbibchapter
Too many }'s. }
Undefined control sequence. \bibliographytypesize
```

I have not used appacite before. I updated my packages with the MiKTeX Updater. Earlier questions like "[compiler complains about apacite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197517/compiler-complains-about-apacite)" were not able to help me.

Do you have any idea where the problem is?

Answer (score 6):

Don't load natbib, apacite will do it in the correct way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}
\cite{doody}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, I am still getting the exact same error (I copied the code you posted). Do you have any further ideas?

Comment: Show your log-file. Delete first the aux-file and the bbl and start anew to avoid that older code interfered.