# What is the use case for the ucs package?

Tags: packages, unicode

The [ucs](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ucs) package (formerly aliased to unicode), provides support for Unicode as a input format, as I understand it.

Under what circumstances should I be using that package, and unicode symbols?

to my knowledge there has been methods for getting most (all?) symbols and accent into TeX since long before Unicode was devised.

Am I better of using the TeX facilities for that when possible,
and unicode when not?

Should I actually be using `ucs` all the time?

Comment: Perhaps you should read [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13067/8528).  I've always heard it is best to avoid this package, so I always did without ever exploring why.  And now I often use LuaTeX as the engine, which uses UTF-8 by default.

Comment: In the past a use case was when Greek input was needed; but in the most recent TeX distributions the problem has been solved and `ucs` is not needed any more for Greek and, by the way, support of Greek with `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is better than it used to be with `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the past a use case for `ucs` was when Greek input was needed; since TeX Live 2013 the situation has changed and full support for Greek input (monotonic and polytonic) is available with

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

provided the `greek` or `polutonikogreek` is passed to `babel`.

Note that the package `ucs` and the `utf8x` options to `inputenc` are not compatible with `biblatex` and, while the `ucs` package has a new maintainer, it doesn't seem to be under active development (and it has several shortcomings, like the infamous `\PrerenderUnicode`).

In case some Unicode character is not available for rendering, you can always define a substitute for it with

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{XXXX}{<code>}
```

where `U+XXXX` is the Unicode code point; alternatively,

```
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{<character>}{<code>}
```

does the same, not requiring to hunt through the code points.

Comment: What is `<code>` in your example? Could you please give a concrete example, perhaps with the `↳` or `✋` or `✅` or ``  UTF-8 characters appearing *literally* in some *generated* UTF-8 LaTeX file. Thanks

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch `<code>` stands for any legal LaTeX code; it *can* contain Unicode characters, provided they have been given a similar definition at call time. Usually it's something like `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2122}{\texttrademark}`, so when LaTeX finds `™` it substitutes `\texttrademark`.

Comment: You have confused me even more...

Comment: How could I use `\texttt{↳}` with that character literally appearing in the `*.tex`  source file ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch You find a font which has the glyph, or build it with picture mode and add `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{21B3}{<the code that produces the symbol>}`