# How to copy text from PDF created by LaTeX?

Tags: copy-paste, latex-to-word

I'm writing some texts in Brazilian Portuguese using LaTeX. Eventually I have to copy/paste some parts of those texts in Word, but with character problems.

I use the following code:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{ucs}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{makeidx}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{times}
    \usepackage[brazil]{babel}
    \begin{document}

 Some text in portuguese with special characters: Coagulação de
partículas à escala microscópica

\end{document}
```

But when I copy/paste the result is:

> Some text in portuguese with special characters: Coagulac¸ ˜ao de
>   part´ıculas `a escala microsc´opica

Someone knows how to avoid this??

Thanks!!

Comment: Don't use `utf8x` use `utf8` instead, and don't load the `ucs` package.  But you need to add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to get the output characters encoded properly. Or use XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX instead.  See [utf8x vs. utf8 (inputenc)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13067) also [fontenc vs inputenc](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44694) and [What is XeTeX exactly and why should I use it?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3393).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to load `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{times}
\begin{document}
 Some text in portuguese with special characters: Coagulação de
 partículas à escala microscópica
 \end{document}
```

here is the result :[image]

and also read this  [fontenc vs inputenc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44694/fontenc-vs-inputenc/44699#44699)

Comment: Really solve the problem!!!!

Comment: Don't load the `ucs` package. It's not needed and will cause other problems. See [What is the use case for the ucs package?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/201078)

Comment: Allan, I don't know why I'm using that package. I erase it and works perfectly, so thank you too for minimize my future problems