# Non-Ascii characters not displaying properly with memoir

Tags: unicode, font-encodings

I am trying to use non-english characters to work in memoir for a book I wrote.  It is science fiction and I am 'making up' an alien language.  While I am no linguist, this is only for a few sort sentences until the technology takes over. The problem is while I have ÄµÊÄ¡£ÄãÇÕãl£¿¬FÚÔ for example.  It looks fine until processed though LaTex.  Then everything becomes ???? ??? ?????.  Packages I am currently using are:

```
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{nextpage}
```

I added

```
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
```

to the preamble.  Then the characters appear properly in the source `.tex` document when viewed in TexStudio but when processed to PDF I get a lot of "unknown character" errors and "malformed UTF-8 sequence". And the characters are either omitted or converted to ???? ??? ???????.

On another note 50.0441° N doesn't display properly either.  I thought that was included with `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`?

Comment: Also see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13067/utf8x-vs-utf8-inputenc

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues with your setup.

1. You need the T1 encoding
2. You need the `textcomp` package
3. The `palatino` package is obsolete
4. The `utf8x` option is not recommended.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\begin{document}

ÄµÊÄ¡£ÄãÇÕãl£¿¬FÚÔ

50.0441° N

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, but adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and changing to `\usepackage{mathpazo}` I still have the same issue (and now even worse since the last comment I posted below when I didn't make any changes to the file).  Ah well, I guess unicode isn't worth the trouble considering I only have a few lines of it in the book.  While I like the look, Tex doesn't seem to.

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <-- new
\usepackage{palatino}
\begin{document}
ÄµÊÄ¡£ÄãÇÕãl£¿¬FÚÔ

50.0441° N
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: Instead of the using the nearly obsolete `palatino` package, you may want to consider loading the more recent `newpxtext` and `newpxmath` packages. If you do so, you can get by with using the `utf8` font encoding system. (As before, you still need to load the `fontenc` package with the option `T1`.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  % <-- note: utf8 instead of utf8x
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\begin{document}
ÄµÊÄ¡£ÄãÇÕãl£¿¬FÚÔ

50.0441° N
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting, I added `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` but still get "utfx error: character 176 seems alone" for line 628 that contains 50.0441° N and "ucs: Unknown Unicode character 867 = U+0363,(ucs) possibly declared in uni-3.def".  I then used my preamble, but only the lines in question after `\begin{document}` And it works fine then.  I don't get it.  Unless it has to do with `\widowpenalty=3500
\clubpenalty=300
\sloppy
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\tolerance=1500
\checkandfixthelayout` that cause a problem after 600 or so lines.

Comment: Ok, now I am really stumped.  I left everything for a few days then when loaded the same .tex file I am getting the same errors of course, but now � characters in the code and before I was at least getting the unicode characters in the code view after enabling T1 encoding and I didn't change a thing since my last comment.  And same as before I get a lot of [U+FFFD] (for example) in the PDF after compile.  I now tried `\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}` removing `palatino` and same issue.  Thanks for the help but I guess I will remove the unicode as it is more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: @DarthNewton - Hmmm, I'm stumped too. Do feel free to post a new query, preferably with a compilable MWE (minimum working example) that generates the problems that you'd like to fix.