# Unicode characters in LaTeX2e

Tags: unicode

I try to to make agda code using unicode characters such as greek characters readable in a LaTeX2e file (which uses a lmcs.cls file http://www.lmcs-online.org/Information/lmcs.cls ). So, I cannot use XeLaTeX instead as recommended to similar problem.

More precisely I added the necessary lines from http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=Main.LiterateAgda
to my file. As described there, it can happen that certain unicode characters are still not yet available and need to be declared separately.

Here is a (possibly minimal) example:

```
 \documentclass{lmcs}

\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{autofe}

\usepackage[greek,english]{babel} %note: after loading autofe

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{"03B9}{\textiota}     % ι
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{"27E6}{\llbracket} 

\begin{document}
ι
⟦
\end{document}
```

The problems with this are: 1)even if there is no error message, \textiota is not displayed in the pdf output, 2) there is an error message
    Undefined control sequence.
    \u-document-10214 #1->\llbracket

Comment: Note that there's a difference between the example code and what is suggested: `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{"03B9}{\textiota}` - note the use of `"`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry, where is the " suggested? When I add it, I still receive the same error message.

Comment: It is in the syntax given on the page you linked to. If you still get an error, post a proper minimal example we can compile to reproduce the error. Please also provide the exact text of the error message and not just a summary or interpretation.

Comment: @cfr @Werner The linked page suggests `”`! The correct character is `"`.

Comment: @PaulGaborit You can only ping one person at a time.

Comment: @PaulGaborit Yes, well. Given that it tells users to use the `utf8x` option, what do you expect? [Not sure about `ucs` - is that useful?]

Comment: @Werner The linked page suggests  `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{”03B9}{\textiota}` instead of `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{"03B9}{\textiota}` (note the difference between `”` and `"`).

Comment: Can you reproduce with a standard class? With `article` it works for me. If not , please give a link for the class.

Comment: I have updated which problems I still have and have added a link to the style file. I know that there have been proposed some solutions to similar problems in other classes, but I have to use the lmcs class.

Comment: [The demo file](http://www.lmcs-online.org/Information/) for `lmcs.cls` works fine when processing with XeLaTeX. LaTeX2e is a *format*; XeTeX is an *engine*; XeLaTeX is shorthand for LaTeX to be processed by XeTeX. There are a few instances where your choice of *engine* matters, but this does not appear to be the case. Perhaps [this glorified glossary](http://seanallred.com/tex/2015/05/25/tex-terminology.html) will help.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't have the freedom to choose a different engine or -format.

Comment: It is true that you can't choose a different format: `\documentclass` means you are using the LaTeX format. But why can't you use a different engine? There is nothing in the `cls` file that seems to forbid it. More importantly, however, the usual advice is to avoid the `ucs` package and `utf8x` encoding. See, e.g., [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/203804/8528); but I think you can find the advice repeated fairly often in different questions (here's [the search results](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=ucs+utf8x)).

Comment: Can you suggest an alternative to the use of ucs and utf8x which does http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=Main.LiterateAgda ?