# LaTeX Error: File `beamerouterthemelsp.sty' not found

Tags: beamer

I'm very new to latex. I copied the code from a template from [this site](https://www.overleaf.com/10433107qdscxhsbszws#/38842353/).

Code:

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\useoutertheme{lsp}
\usepackage{lsptitle}

\def\mytoday{\two@digits{\number\day}.\two@digits{\number\month}.\number\year}

\usepackage{xspace,multicol}
\newcommand{\latex}{\LaTeX\xspace}

\newcounter{lastpagemainpart}
\footnotesep0pt
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{}
\usefootnotetemplate{
  \noindent
  \insertfootnotemark\insertfootnotetext}

\let\beamerfn=\footnote
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{%
\let\oldfnsize=\footnotesize%
\let\footnotesize=\tiny%
\beamerfn<\thebeamerpauses->{#1}%
\let\footnotesize=\oldfnsize}
\date{05.03.2015}

\usepackage{eurosym} 
\usepackage{ogonek}  % Dabrowska
%\usepackage{libertine}

\renewcommand{\centerline}[1]{\hfill#1\hfill\hfill\mbox{}}

\title{Language Science Press}
\institute{FU Berlin}
\author{Firstname Lastname}

\begin{document}
\lspbeamertitle
\section{Hintergrund}

\frame{
\frametitle{Hintergrund}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item first
\item sth
\item lala
\item c
\end{itemize}
} 

\section{Organisation}
\subsection{Level 2}
\subsubsection{Ebene 3}

\frame{
\frametitle{Gemeinschaftsprojekt}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item 
\end{itemize}
}

\setcounter{framenumber}{\thelastpagemainpart}
\end{document}
```

I paste the code into MikTex - Texworks editor. It downloaded some packages like beamer. later when I tried to compile the code, I found the Error

```
! LaTeX Error: File `beamerouterthemelsp.sty' not found.
```

How to get rid of this error!!

Comment: Did you download the file `beamerouterthemelsp.sty` from https://www.overleaf.com/10433107qdscxhsbszws#/38842349/?

Comment: oops no.. i didn't ...

Comment: sorry i didn't knew it..  I managed to get the complete project [1][from here] [1] : https://github.com/langsci/lsp-beamer    Let me try now

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please add the minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem always without providing a link. You can just write the code directly to your question.(i will copied now for you)

Comment: @Pzy64 Please try with the version from https://www.overleaf.com/10433107qdscxhsbszws#/38842349/ (the one from github seems broken - I cannot make it to compile)

Comment: @samcarter Didn't work , In that github project ,the author referenced each file absolutely. `\ProvidesPackageRCS` from his directory structure. It might work if I changed it

Comment: @Pzy64 The `\ProvidesPackageRCS` is not the problem - but please use the one from overleaf instead of trying to repair the one from github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message already informed you that `beamerouterthemelsp.sty` is missing. It is available on overleaf, to download it select the option `Download as zip`, the missing file will be included in the zip.

[image]

---

Off-topic: please read [utf8x vs. utf8 (inputenc)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13067/utf8x-vs-utf8-inputenc) to decide if you really want to use `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`.