# Table of Contents problem for an APA-style thesis

Tags: table-of-contents, apa6

I encountered a problem with my ToC using APA style. The title appears twice in the table. I tried several things, but I believe it is concerned with the use of the apa6 document class. Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,natbib]{apa6}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
%excel2latex
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{titlesec}
%\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]
  %{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\title{\LARGE Example Title}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Can you make your document compilable, and remove any packages that aren't needed to show the problem.  It will make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: As a side comment, the `apa6` class is designed to meet the requirements for submitting to APA journals. It's probably not an appropriate class for a thesis.  But you can add `donotrepeattitle` to the class options to remove the extra title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `apa6` document class is designed specifically to meet the requirements for submitting articles to APA journals. It's really not appropriate for a thesis.  It's likely that you will end up having to undo many more things to make it usable as such, and you would be better of formatting your thesis using one of the standard classes plus `titlesec` or a complete class like `memoir`.

But the simple problem you have right now can be solved with a class option:

```
\documentclass[donotrepeattitle]{apa6}
```

Here's a complete minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,natbib,donotrepeattitle]{apa6}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\title{\Large Example Title}
\author{An author}
\abstract{Abstract}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

I've trimmed down your code to make a minimal example, and changed `utf8x` to `utf8`, since `utf8x` shouldn't be used. See [utf8x vs. utf8 (inputenc)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13067/2693).

[image: output of contents papge]

Comment: Thank you very much, problem was solved this way. Sadly I am forced to write my thesis in APA.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. But APA is a style of formatting, and most cases it refers to citations and bibliography formatting, not the literal APA journal submission format.  See also [What is the relationship between natbib, apacite package, and apa document class?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/263793).

Comment: Hey Alan, I would have another question regarding the ToC. I would like to add my \listoffigures and \listoftables as an entry into my ToC above the Tables and Figures entry. Is that possible?

Comment: @CesiumNotch After your `\listoffigures` add `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listfigurename}`. Same for list of tables (but replace `figure` with `table`...)