# Why does utf8 not allow Cyrillic letters in listings when utf8x does?

Tags: listings, unicode, cyrillic

Answers in [utf8x vs. utf8 (inputenc)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13067/utf8x-vs-utf8-inputenc) say that `utf8x` shouldn't generally be used. However, with `listings`,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    inputencoding=utf8,
    extendedchars=\true,
    literate={а}{{\selectfont\char224}}1
    {б}{{\selectfont\char225}}1
    {в}{{\selectfont\char226}}1
    {г}{{\selectfont\char227}}1
    {д}{{\selectfont\char228}}1
    {е}{{\selectfont\char229}}1
    {ё}{{\"e}}1
    {ж}{{\selectfont\char230}}1
    {з}{{\selectfont\char231}}1
    {и}{{\selectfont\char232}}1
    {й}{{\selectfont\char233}}1
    {к}{{\selectfont\char234}}1
    {л}{{\selectfont\char235}}1
    {м}{{\selectfont\char236}}1
    {н}{{\selectfont\char237}}1
    {о}{{\selectfont\char238}}1
    {п}{{\selectfont\char239}}1
    {р}{{\selectfont\char240}}1
    {с}{{\selectfont\char241}}1
    {т}{{\selectfont\char242}}1
    {у}{{\selectfont\char243}}1
    {ф}{{\selectfont\char244}}1
    {х}{{\selectfont\char245}}1
    {ц}{{\selectfont\char246}}1
    {ч}{{\selectfont\char247}}1
    {ш}{{\selectfont\char248}}1
    {щ}{{\selectfont\char249}}1
    {ъ}{{\selectfont\char250}}1
    {ы}{{\selectfont\char251}}1
    {ь}{{\selectfont\char252}}1
    {э}{{\selectfont\char253}}1
    {ю}{{\selectfont\char254}}1
    {я}{{\selectfont\char255}}1
    {А}{{\selectfont\char192}}1
    {Б}{{\selectfont\char193}}1
    {В}{{\selectfont\char194}}1
    {Г}{{\selectfont\char195}}1
    {Д}{{\selectfont\char196}}1
    {Е}{{\selectfont\char197}}1
    {Ё}{{\"E}}1
    {Ж}{{\selectfont\char198}}1
    {З}{{\selectfont\char199}}1
    {И}{{\selectfont\char200}}1
    {Й}{{\selectfont\char201}}1
    {К}{{\selectfont\char202}}1
    {Л}{{\selectfont\char203}}1
    {М}{{\selectfont\char204}}1
    {Н}{{\selectfont\char205}}1
    {О}{{\selectfont\char206}}1
    {П}{{\selectfont\char207}}1
    {Р}{{\selectfont\char208}}1
    {С}{{\selectfont\char209}}1
    {Т}{{\selectfont\char210}}1
    {У}{{\selectfont\char211}}1
    {Ф}{{\selectfont\char212}}1
    {Х}{{\selectfont\char213}}1
    {Ц}{{\selectfont\char214}}1
    {Ч}{{\selectfont\char215}}1
    {Ш}{{\selectfont\char216}}1
    {Щ}{{\selectfont\char217}}1
    {Ъ}{{\selectfont\char218}}1
    {Ы}{{\selectfont\char219}}1
    {Ь}{{\selectfont\char220}}1
    {Э}{{\selectfont\char221}}1
    {Ю}{{\selectfont\char222}}1
    {Я}{{\selectfont\char223}}1
}
\begin{document}
\lstinline|а|
\end{document}
```

works correctly and shows Cyrillic `а`. Replacing `utf8x` with `utf8` in both places shows `Я` instead.

Does the above `literate` "magic spell" (since I don't understand how it works) need to be changed for `utf8`?

(I don't want to switch to XeTeX at the moment.)

Comment: As always here, please post a full minimal example instead of sniplets. Then it is a lot easier for others to copy and test your code.

Comment: @daleif Changed to a full example.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Do you mean `listingsutf8`? `listings-utf` isn't listed at https://ctan.org/pkg/:L and searching Google doesn't bring it up for me. I initially understood `listingsutf8`'s documentation to say that it only supports `\lstinputlisting` and not `\lstlisting`. Still tried it now and after removing `literate` it works... except still changing some characters to `я`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov: Yes, I meant `listingsutf8` -- I couldn't remember the name correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the wrong char both with ucs and without it. The problem is that you use `\true` instead of `true` for the `extendedchars` option and so effectively set it to false. I would also suggest to replace the numbers with the commands `\cyra` etc, you find them in t2aenc.def or t2aend.dfu.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    inputencoding=utf8,
    extendedchars=true, %compare with false instead
    literate={а}{\cyra}1
    {б}{{\selectfont\char225}}1
    {в}{{\selectfont\char226}}1
    {г}{{\selectfont\char227}}1
    {д}{{\selectfont\char228}}1
    {е}{{\selectfont\char229}}1
    {ё}{{\"e}}1
    {ж}{{\selectfont\char230}}1
    {з}{{\selectfont\char231}}1
    {и}{{\selectfont\char232}}1
    {й}{{\selectfont\char233}}1
    {к}{{\selectfont\char234}}1
    {л}{{\selectfont\char235}}1
    {м}{{\selectfont\char236}}1
    {н}{{\selectfont\char237}}1
    {о}{{\selectfont\char238}}1
    {п}{{\selectfont\char239}}1
    {р}{{\selectfont\char240}}1
    {с}{{\selectfont\char241}}1
    {т}{{\selectfont\char242}}1
    {у}{{\selectfont\char243}}1
    {ф}{{\selectfont\char244}}1
    {х}{{\selectfont\char245}}1
    {ц}{{\selectfont\char246}}1
    {ч}{{\selectfont\char247}}1
    {ш}{{\selectfont\char248}}1
    {щ}{{\selectfont\char249}}1
    {ъ}{{\selectfont\char250}}1
    {ы}{{\selectfont\char251}}1
    {ь}{{\selectfont\char252}}1
    {э}{{\selectfont\char253}}1
    {ю}{{\selectfont\char254}}1
    {я}{{\selectfont\char255}}1
    {А}{{\selectfont\char192}}1
    {Б}{{\selectfont\char193}}1
    {В}{{\selectfont\char194}}1
    {Г}{{\selectfont\char195}}1
    {Д}{{\selectfont\char196}}1
    {Е}{{\selectfont\char197}}1
    {Ё}{{\"E}}1
    {Ж}{{\selectfont\char198}}1
    {З}{{\selectfont\char199}}1
    {И}{{\selectfont\char200}}1
    {Й}{{\selectfont\char201}}1
    {К}{{\selectfont\char202}}1
    {Л}{{\selectfont\char203}}1
    {М}{{\selectfont\char204}}1
    {Н}{{\selectfont\char205}}1
    {О}{{\selectfont\char206}}1
    {П}{{\selectfont\char207}}1
    {Р}{{\selectfont\char208}}1
    {С}{{\selectfont\char209}}1
    {Т}{{\selectfont\char210}}1
    {У}{{\selectfont\char211}}1
    {Ф}{{\selectfont\char212}}1
    {Х}{{\selectfont\char213}}1
    {Ц}{{\selectfont\char214}}1
    {Ч}{{\selectfont\char215}}1
    {Ш}{{\selectfont\char216}}1
    {Щ}{{\selectfont\char217}}1
    {Ъ}{{\selectfont\char218}}1
    {Ы}{{\selectfont\char219}}1
    {Ь}{{\selectfont\char220}}1
    {Э}{{\selectfont\char221}}1
    {Ю}{{\selectfont\char222}}1
    {Я}{{\selectfont\char223}}1
}
\begin{document}  
\lstinline|абЮ|
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A few Russian posts insist `true` doesn't work for them and `\true` is necessary. I didn't double-check after finding the `literate` trick, unfortunately (which I think those posts were missing).

Answer (score 5):

The main error is in `\true` instead of `true`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    inputencoding=utf8,
    extendedchars=true,
    literate=
    {а}{{\cyra}}1
    {б}{{\cyrb}}1
    {в}{{\cyrv}}1
    {г}{{\cyrg}}1
    {д}{{\cyrd}}1
    {е}{{\cyre}}1
    {ё}{\"{\cyre}}1
    {ж}{{\cyrzh}}1
    {з}{{\cyrz}}1
    {и}{{\cyri}}1
    {й}{{\cyrishrt}}1
    {к}{{\cyrk}}1
    {л}{{\cyrl}}1
    {м}{{\cyrm}}1
    {н}{{\cyrn}}1
    {о}{{\cyro}}1
    {п}{{\cyrp}}1
    {р}{{\cyrr}}1
    {с}{{\cyrs}}1
    {т}{{\cyrt}}1
    {у}{{\cyru}}1
    {ф}{{\cyrf}}1
    {х}{{\cyrh}}1
    {ц}{{\cyrc}}1
    {ч}{{\cyrch}}1
    {ш}{{\cyrsh}}1
    {щ}{{\cyrshch}}1
    {ъ}{{\cyrhrdsn}}1
    {ы}{{\cyrery}}1
    {ь}{{\cyrsftsn}}1
    {э}{{\cyrerev}}1
    {ю}{{\cyryu}}1
    {я}{{\cyrya}}1
    {А}{{\CYRA}}1
    {Б}{{\CYRB}}1
    {В}{{\CYRV}}1
    {Г}{{\CYRG}}1
    {Д}{{\CYR96}}1
    {Е}{{\CYRE}}1
    {Ё}{{\"{\CYRE}}}1
    {Ж}{{\CYRZH}}1
    {З}{{\CYRZ}}1
    {И}{{\CYRI}}1
    {Й}{{\CYRISHRT}}1
    {К}{{\CYRK}}1
    {Л}{{\CYRL}}1
    {М}{{\CYRM}}1
    {Н}{{\CYRN}}1
    {О}{{\CYRO}}1
    {П}{{\CYRP}}1
    {Р}{{\CYRR}}1
    {С}{{\CYRS}}1
    {Т}{{\CYRT}}1
    {У}{{\CYRU}}1
    {Ф}{{\CYRF}}1
    {Х}{{\CYRH}}1
    {Ц}{{\CYRC}}1
    {Ч}{{\CYRCH}}1
    {Ш}{{\CYRSH}}1
    {Щ}{{\CYRSHCH}}1
    {Ъ}{{\CYRHRDSN}}1
    {Ы}{{\CYRERY}}1
    {Ь}{{\CYRSFTSN}}1
    {Э}{{\CYREREV}}1
    {Ю}{{\CYRYU}}1
    {Я}{{\CYRYA}}1
}
\begin{document}
\lstinline|абвгдеёжз...юя|
\end{document}
```

[image]