# Cyrillic characters in lstlisting

Tags: xetex, listings, texstudio

I try to write some cyrillic text in a source code block:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={asdfa},label={lst:tokens},language=SQL]
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM cards
WHERE description ILIKE '%#НОМЕР#%') AS PhoneNumber,
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM cards
WHERE description ILIKE '%#ГОС.НОМЕР#%') AS LicensePlateNumber
\end{lstlisting}
```

style is set like below:

```
\lstset{
    language=SQL,frame=ltrb,framesep=5pt,basicstyle=\normalsize,
    keywordstyle=\ttfamily\color{OliveGreen},
    identifierstyle=\ttfamily\color{CadetBlue}\bfseries, 
    commentstyle=\color{Brown},
    stringstyle=\ttfamily,
    showstringspaces=true,
    escapeinside={<--}{-->},
    extendedchars=\true,
    literate={а}{\cyra}1
    {б}{{\selectfont\char225}}1
    {в}{{\selectfont\char226}}1
    {г}{{\selectfont\char227}}1
    {д}{{\selectfont\char228}}1
    {е}{{\selectfont\char229}}1
    {ё}{{\"e}}1
    {ж}{{\selectfont\char230}}1
    {з}{{\selectfont\char231}}1
    {и}{{\selectfont\char232}}1
    ...
    }
```

None of the cyrillic characters is displayed. I tried to enclose cyrillic in rare used characters ([Listing with mixed english and russian symbols in comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108692/listing-with-mixed-english-and-russian-symbols-in-comments)), but it didn't work either. Usage of `extendedchars=true` instead of `\true` ([Why does utf8 not allow Cyrillic letters in listings when utf8x does?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/415779/why-does-utf8-not-allow-cyrillic-letters-in-listings-when-utf8x-does)) doesn't help. I've found suggestion to use `mintex` (the first link), but I will have to create a list of listings.

I also have following imports at the beginning:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian, english]{babel}
```

Use of `polyglossia` with Russian as an additional language didn't help as well.

How can I make this thing work with cyrillic symbols?

**Edit**: Here are the imports:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{pics/}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian, english]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[acronym,automake]{glossaries}
\usepackage{xcolor,listings}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\setmonofont{Courier New}
\input{common/lststyles}
```

None of the packages are applied after this.

**Edit 2**:
This sample code works, although in a weird manner:

```
\lstdefinestyle{code-style-sql}{
    belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,
    xleftmargin=\parindent,
    identifierstyle=\color{blue},
    language=SQL,                % the language of the code
    backgroundcolor=\color{backgray},       % choose the background color; you must add \usepackage{color} or \usepackage{xcolor}; should come as last argument  
    commentstyle=\color{codegray},        % comment style
    keywordstyle=\color{codeblue}\bfseries,    % keyword style
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},      % the style that is used for the line-numbers
    stringstyle=\color{codeblue},        % string literal style
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily\footnotesize,  % Размер и тип шрифта, the size of the fonts that are used for the code
    breakatwhitespace=false,               % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
    breaklines=true,                  % Перенос строк, the size of the fonts that are used for the code       
    captionpos=lt,                          % sets the caption-position to bottom               
    keepspaces=true,                % keeps spaces in text, useful for keeping indentation of code (possibly needs columns=flexible)             
    numbers=left,                          % where to put the line-numbers; possible values are (none, left, right)
    numbersep=5pt,                     % how far the line-numbers are from the code       
    stepnumber=1,                          % the step between two line-numbers. If it's 1, each line will be numbered
    showspaces=false,           % show spaces everywhere adding particular underscores; it overrides 'showstringspaces'   
    showstringspaces=false,    % underline spaces within strings only    
    showtabs=false,             % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores     
    tabsize=2,          % Размер табуляции, sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
    %  frame=single,               % Рамка, adds a frame around the code
    %  frame=TB,
    literate={--}{{-{}-}}2,     % Корректно отображать двойной дефис
    literate={---}{{-{}-{}-}}3,  % Корректно отображать тройной дефис
    escapeinside={<--}{-->}
}
\lstset{style=code-style-sql}
```

It moves cyrillic text to the left apostrophe and leaves the signs at the right side: `'ГОСНОМЕР%#.#%'` instead of `'%#ГОС.НОМЕР#%'`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Would you please merge those code snippets to a _complete example_ (also called MWE as mentioned by @DG' )?

Comment: The commands such as `{б}{{\selectfont\char225}}` are incorrect. There might originally have been a `\fontencoding{T2A}` before `\selectfont` in a document for PDFTeX. However, a document in XeTeX should just use Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

You can use XeLaTeX, but you have to manually add support for the basic (Russian) Cyrillic alphabet.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

% a main font that supports Cyrillic; use your preferred one
\setmainfont{NewCM10}[
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  ItalicFont=*-Italic,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
]
\setmonofont{Courier New}

\lstset{
  language=SQL,
  frame=ltrb,
  framesep=5pt,
  basicstyle=\normalsize,
  keywordstyle=\ttfamily\color{OliveGreen},
  identifierstyle=\ttfamily\color{CadetBlue}\bfseries, 
  commentstyle=\color{Brown},
  stringstyle=\ttfamily,
  showstringspaces=true,
  escapeinside={<--}{-->},
}

\makeatletter % see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/320345
\lst@InputCatcodes
\def\lst@DefEC{%
 \lst@CCECUse \lst@ProcessLetter
  ^^80^^81^^82^^83^^84^^85^^86^^87^^88^^89^^8a^^8b^^8c^^8d^^8e^^8f%
  ^^90^^91^^92^^93^^94^^95^^96^^97^^98^^99^^9a^^9b^^9c^^9d^^9e^^9f%
  ^^a0^^a1^^a2^^a3^^a4^^a5^^a6^^a7^^a8^^a9^^aa^^ab^^ac^^ad^^ae^^af%
  ^^b0^^b1^^b2^^b3^^b4^^b5^^b6^^b7^^b8^^b9^^ba^^bb^^bc^^bd^^be^^bf%
  ^^c0^^c1^^c2^^c3^^c4^^c5^^c6^^c7^^c8^^c9^^ca^^cb^^cc^^cd^^ce^^cf%
  ^^d0^^d1^^d2^^d3^^d4^^d5^^d6^^d7^^d8^^d9^^da^^db^^dc^^dd^^de^^df%
  ^^e0^^e1^^e2^^e3^^e4^^e5^^e6^^e7^^e8^^e9^^ea^^eb^^ec^^ed^^ee^^ef%
  ^^f0^^f1^^f2^^f3^^f4^^f5^^f6^^f7^^f8^^f9^^fa^^fb^^fc^^fd^^fe^^ff%
  ^^^^20ac^^^^0153^^^^0152%
  % Basic Cyrillic alphabet coverage
  ^^^^0410^^^^0411^^^^0412^^^^0413^^^^0414^^^^0415^^^^0416^^^^0417%
  ^^^^0418^^^^0419^^^^041a^^^^041b^^^^041c^^^^041d^^^^041e^^^^041f%
  ^^^^0420^^^^0421^^^^0422^^^^0423^^^^0424^^^^0425^^^^0426^^^^0427%
  ^^^^0428^^^^0429^^^^042a^^^^042b^^^^042c^^^^042d^^^^042e^^^^042f%
  ^^^^0430^^^^0431^^^^0432^^^^0433^^^^0434^^^^0435^^^^0436^^^^0437%
  ^^^^0438^^^^0439^^^^043a^^^^043b^^^^043c^^^^043d^^^^043e^^^^043f%
  ^^^^0440^^^^0441^^^^0442^^^^0443^^^^0444^^^^0445^^^^0446^^^^0447%
  ^^^^0448^^^^0449^^^^044a^^^^044b^^^^044c^^^^044d^^^^044e^^^^044f%
  ^^^^0401^^^^0451%
  %%%
  ^^00}
\lst@RestoreCatcodes
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={asdfa},label={lst:tokens},language=SQL]
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM cards
WHERE description ILIKE '%#НОМЕР#%') AS PhoneNumber,
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM cards
WHERE description ILIKE '%#ГОС.НОМЕР#%') AS LicensePlateNumber
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Note that you shouldn't load `inputenc` and `fontenc`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Switching to pdfLaTeX from XeTeX solves the problem.

Comment: Switching compiler is usually not a solution as there are other situations where one is asked to switch from pdftex to xetex. For non-Latin languages in particular, pdftex is just unpleasant.