# Subfigure without figure

Tags: subfloats

I have two figures which I have already combined next to each other (horizontally) into one .eps figure via Stata. How do I now use the subfigure command to label both separately (horizontally). Leaving out the /includegraphics command twice within subfigure command (as I have already inserted the combined graph using includegraphics) does not give me the desired result. Is this not possible? Any work around?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace,graphicx,epstopdf,amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,versionPO}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\begin{figure}[htb]%
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=7in]{Figure1.eps}
    \subfloat[label 1]%
    \qquad
    \subfloat[label 2]%
    \caption{2 Figures side by side}%
    \label{fig:example}%
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. If I turn your code into a complete document, it compiles without error. Can you tell us exactly which error you get, and perhaps make a complete minimal working example? (See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ for more on MWEs.)

Comment: Tried to edit my question.

Comment: A couple of things: 1) The first code you posted used syntax from the `subcaption` package, the new code uses syntax from `subfig`. Do you have any requirements for which package to use? 2) `versionPO` is not a standard package (i.e. it is not on https://ctan.org/), so if it's not needed, it would be better to remove it from the example.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, versionPO is not mandatory for me (I use a template). As far as I understood, the subfig syntax is the newer (more often used) syntax. As I am a newbie to LaTeX, I think I don't have any requirements for the package. I am mostly interested in getting to know whether I have to recreate all my figures to have separate ones or whether I can use existing syntax to achieve the subcaption despite not having two separated figures. @TorbjørnT.

Comment: `subfig` might be more used, but `subcaption` is newer. (There is also a package called `subfigure`, but that is considered deprecated I believe, one of the other two should be used.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `subcaption` package and its `\subcaption` macro, as in the example below.

[image]

A couple of unrelated comments:

- it's not recommended to use `utf8x` for `inputenc` ([utf8x vs. utf8 (inputenc)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13067/utf8x-vs-utf8-inputenc)). I believe `utf8`became default last year, so if you have a new system then you don't need `inputenc` at all, but anyway prefer `utf8` over `utf8x` if loading it.
- `epsfig` is just a wrapper over `graphicx` I believe, and today it's not needed at all. Remove that, and keep just `graphicx`.

---

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]%
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=10pt,position=bottom}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-16x10}
    \parbox{0.45\linewidth}{\subcaption{First subfig}}\hfill
    \parbox{0.45\linewidth}{\subcaption{Second subfig}}
    \caption{2 Figures side by side}%
    \label{fig:example}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I increase the space between the figure and the subcaption? 
I tried /midskip (no effect), \setlength{\abovecaptionskip} (don't want that it applies to my general caption setup). @Torbjørn T.

Comment: @PSA Add `\captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=10pt,position=bottom}` inside the `figure` environment.