# Using TeX Live version 2022 gives compilation error (but no issue with any previous version)

Tags: beamer, texlive, compiling

I am using Overleaf, and in recycling a previous preamble I encountered the compilation error "Argument of � has an extra }." which is no issue when I use 2021 and back Tex Live. Here is a one-slide example:

```
\documentclass[notes,11pt,xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}         % Include 'handout' for a handout version. Delete aspectratio=169 to have a standard format 4:3 | Last option allows to obtain colors from list https://de.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Using_colours_in_LaTeX

\usepackage[english]{babel}                                   % Set language
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}                      % Set encoding
%\useoutertheme{miniframes}             % to add circles in the navigation bar 
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vspace*{.5em}}{} %to shift frame titles up/down
 
\mode<presentation>                                                         % Set options
{
  \usetheme{default}                                                 % Set theme
  \usecolortheme{default}                                        % Set colors
  \usefonttheme{default}                                          % Set font theme
  %\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]         % Set caption to be numbered
  \setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[circle]
%  \setbeamersize{text margin right = 10pt}
}
 
% Uncomment this to have the outline at the beginning of each section highlighted.
%\AtBeginSection[]
%{
%  \begin{frame}{Outline}
%    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
%  \end{frame}
%}
 
\usepackage{amsfonts}                                            %Math stuff
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm} %Bold in math mode
\usepackage{graphicx}                                             % For including figures
\usepackage{hyperref}                                             % For cross-referencing
\usepackage{animate} %To create GIFs
 
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number] % To replace the footer line in all slides with a simple slide count uncomment this line
 
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % To remove the navigation symbols from the bottom of all slides uncomment this line
 
\newenvironment{wideitemize}{\itemize\addtolength{\itemsep}{100pt}}{\enditemize}
 
\settowidth{\leftmargini}{\usebeamertemplate{itemize item}}
\addtolength{\leftmargini}{\labelsep} % To shift the itemize items to the left uncomment this line

\definecolor{foo}{rgb}{0.2,0.2,0.7} % To define color for citations

\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{multirow}   %Allows to split slides into columns
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\usepackage{adjustbox}
% *****************************************************************
% siunitx
% *****************************************************************
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\sisetup{group-separator = {,}, group-minimum-digits = 4,
        detect-mode,
        tight-spacing           = true,
        input-signs             = ,
        input-symbols           = ,
        input-open-uncertainty  = ,
        input-close-uncertainty = ,
        table-align-text-pre    = false,
        table-space-text-pre    = (,
        } % centering in tables
\title{ABC}
\date{}
 
\begin{document}
 
\begin{frame}[plain, noframenumbering]
\vspace{-15pt}
\titlepage
\vspace{20pt}\centering Seminar
\end{frame}
 


\end{document}
```

Am I using an outdated command here? Any help in tracking down the issue would be appreciated.
Thanks all

Comment: No errors here. Have you deleted auxiliary files when changed TeXLive version? (BTW --- get rid of `utf8x` inputenc, not needed and probably harmful).

Comment: @Rmano You, kind human, directed me to the root of the problem.  Removing the ```\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}``` did away with the issue. Someone here, in comments, says that line of code does nothing anymore since August 2022: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13067/utf8x-vs-utf8-inputenc

Comment: Unrelated to the problem: you don't need to load all these `default` themes, as the name says, beamer loads them by default. You also don't need `\usepackage{amsfonts}                                            
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{hyperref}`, beamer loads all of them for you

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you for the tips! Parsimonious code is always better :)

Comment: I believe overleaf's 2022 release was before utf8x was made a no-op, so deleting it is required