# Color table rows when using multirow and multicolumn

Tags: color, multicolumn, multirow

I made a table that uses multicolumn and multirow.

I have not been able to find out how to color the rows correctly, I found some questions on this net but they do not work out for me.

Any one can help me with this one?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{tableGreaterHeader}{RGB}{28, 69, 135}
\definecolor{tableHeader}{RGB}{211, 47, 47}
\definecolor{tableLineOne}{RGB}{245, 245, 245}
\definecolor{tableLineTwo}{RGB}{224, 224, 224}
\rowcolors{1}{tableLineOne}{tableLineTwo}
\arrayrulecolor{pink}
\begin{document} 
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \begin{center}
            \caption{Minimal booktabs example.}
            \label{tab:table1}
              \begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
            \begin{tabular}{l l l c c c c c c c c c c c c c c }
                \toprule\rowcolor{tableGreaterHeader}
                \\\rowcolor{tableGreaterHeader}
  \multirow{2}{*}[-1em]{{\cellcolor{tableGreaterHeader}}Base material} & \multirow{2}{*}[-1em]{Thickness} & \multirow{2}{*}[-1em]{Amperage} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Voltage} & \multicolumn{9}{c}{Wire feed speed}\\
\cmidrule(lr){4-8} \cmidrule(lr){9-17} \\\rowcolor{tableGreaterHeader}
{} & {} & {} & \(\mathrm{CO}_2\)    &   Ar 75 \% + \(\mathrm{CO}_2\) 25 \%  &   He + Ar + \(\mathrm{CO}_2\) &   Ar  &   Ar 98 \% + \(\mathrm{O}_2\) 2 \% & Steel .030 & Steel 0.035 & Steel 0.045 & Stainless steel 0.035 & Stainless steel 0.045 & Stainless steel 0.063 & Al 4043 0.035 & Al 4043 0.045 & Al 4043 0.063 \\
\midrule % <-- Midrule here
\showrowcolors
\rowcolor{tableHeader}
\multicolumn{17}{c}{\textcolor{white}{Short circuit transfer mode}} \\
\midrule
Steel   &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       \\
&   22 ga   &   40 - 55 &   16 - 17 &   15 - 16 &   -   &   -   &   -   &   90 - 100    &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   \\  
&   20 ga   &   50 - 60 &   17 - 18 &   15 - 16 &   -   &   -   &   -   &   120 - 135   &   105 - 115   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   \\  
&   18 ga   &   70 - 80 &   18 - 19 &   16 - 17 &   -   &   -   &   -   &   150 - 175   &   140 - 160   &   70  &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   \\  
&   16 ga   &   90 - 110    &   19 - 20 &   17 - 18 &   -   &   -   &   -   &   220 - 250   &   180 - 220   &   90 - 110    &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   \\  
&   14 ga   &   120 - 130   &   20 - 21 &   17 - 18 &   -   &   -   &   -   &   250 - 340   &   240 - 260   &   120 - 130   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   \\  
&     1/8   &   140 - 150   &   21 - 22 &   18 - 19 &   -   &       &       &   -   &   280 - 300   &   140 - 150   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   \\  
&     3/16  &   160 - 170   &   21 - 22 &   18 - 19 &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   320 - 340   &   160 - 175   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   \\  
&     1/4   &   180 - 190   &   23 - 24 &   21 - 22 &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   360 - 380   &   185 - 195   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   \\  
&     5/16  &   200 - 210   &   23 - 24 &   21 - 22 &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   400 - 420   &   210 - 220   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   \\  
&     3/8   &   220 - 250   &   24 - 25 &   23 - 24 &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   420 - 520   &   220 - 270   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   \\  
&     1/2   &   300 &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   375 &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   \\  
Stainless steel &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       \\
&   18 ga   &   50 - 60 &   -   &   -   &   19 - 20 &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   120 - 150   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   \\  
&   16 ga   &   70 - 80 &   -   &   -   &   19 - 20 &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   180 - 205   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   \\  
&   14 ga   &   90 - 110    &   -   &   -   &   20 - 21 &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   230 - 275   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   \\  
&   12 ga   &   120 - 130   &   -   &   -   &   20 - 21 &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   300 - 325   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   \\  
&     3/16  &   140 - 150   &   -   &   -   &   21 - 22 &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   350 - 375   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   \\  
&     1/4   &   160 - 170   &   -   &   -   &   21 - 22 &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   400 - 425   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   \\  
&     5/16  &   180 - 190   &   -   &   -   &   21 - 22 &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   450 - 475   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   \\  
&     3/8   &   200 - 210   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   \\  
&     7/16  &   220 - 250   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   \\  
&     1/2   &   300 - 325   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   \\\midrule  \rowcolor{tableHeader}
\multicolumn{17}{c}{\textcolor{white}{Spray arc transfer mode}} \\

\midrule                                                                                                                                
Steel   &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       \\
&   22 ga   &   50 - 60 &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   120 - 135   &   105 - 115   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   \\  
&   20 ga   &   70 - 80 &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   150 - 175   &   140 - 160   &   70  &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   \\  
&   18 ga   &   90 - 110    &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   220 - 250   &   180 - 220   &   90 - 110    &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   \\  
&   16 ga   &   120 - 130   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   250 - 340   &   240 - 260   &   120 - 130   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   \\  
&   14 ga   &   140 - 150   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   280 - 300   &   140 - 150   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   \\  
&     1/8   &   160 - 170   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   23 - 24 &   -   &   320 - 340   &   160 - 175   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   \\  
&     3/16  &   180 - 190   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   24 - 25 &   -   &   360 - 380   &   185 - 195   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   \\  
&     1/4   &   200 - 210   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   24 - 25 &   -   &   400 - 420   &   210 - 220   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   \\  
&     5/16  &   220 - 250   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   25 - 26 &   -   &   420 - 520   &   220 - 270   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   \\  
&     3/8   &   300 &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   26 - 27 &   -   &   -   &   375 &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   \\  
&     1/2   &   315 &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   29 - 30 &   -   &   -   &   390 &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   \\  
Stainless steel &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       \\
&   18 ga   &   70 - 80 &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   180 - 205   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   \\  
&   16 ga   &   90 - 110    &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   230 - 275   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   \\  
&   14 ga   &   120 - 130   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   300 - 325   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   \\  
&   12 ga   &   140 - 150   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   350 - 375   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   \\  
&     3/16  &   160 - 170   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   23 - 24 &   -   &   -   &   -   &   400 - 425   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   \\  
&     1/4   &   180 - 190   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   24 - 25 &   -   &   -   &   -   &   450 - 475   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   \\  
&     5/16  &   200 - 210   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   24 - 25 &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   250 - 300   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   \\  
&     3/8   &   250 - 275   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   25 - 26 &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   140 - 170   &   -   &   -   &   -   \\  
&     7/16  &   275 - 300   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   26 - 27 &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   170 - 200   &   -   &   -   &   -   \\  
&     1/2   &   300 - 325   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   27 - 32 &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   200 - 230   &   -   &   -   &   -   \\  
Aluminum    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       \\
&     1/8   &   110 - 130   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   21 - 22 &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   350 - 400   &   240 - 270   &   -   \\  
&     3/16  &   140 - 150   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   23 - 24 &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   425 - 450   &   300 - 325   &   -   \\  
&     1/4   &   180 - 210   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   24 - 25 &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   350 - 370   &   170 - 185   \\  
&     5/16  &   200 - 230   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   26 - 27 &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   400 - 425   &   200 - 210   \\  
&     3/8   &   220 - 250   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   26 - 28 &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   450 - 480   &   220 - 230   \\  
&     7/16  &   280 &   -   &   -   &   -   &   28 - 29 &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   240 - 270   \\  
&     1/2   &   300 &   -   &   -   &   -   &   29 - 30 &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   -   &   290 - 300   \\  

                \bottomrule % <-- Bottomrule here
            \end{tabular}
            \end{adjustbox}
        \end{center}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Also, maybe a different question but there is white space surrounding the rules of the table, how can I get rid of them?

This is what I got

[image: MWE]

Comment: What do you expect your table to look like? Note that the `booktabs` package adds some spacing between the table rows, if this is not what you want, just use `\hline`s and don't load the booktabs package. Unrelated: you should [probably not use](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13070/47927) `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`.

Comment: You might want to have a look at packages such as `tabularray` that give you more flexibility with coloring and spacing.

Comment: Your table is far to wide for show it readable  in portrait orientation. Is its rotating to landscape an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I already mentioned, your table is huge and cannot be fit in readable form in one page. A possible option is

- increase text block size with use of the`geometry` package
- use `\footnotesize` font size for table body
- use `\scriptsize` for column headers

Beside this I suggest to use `siunitx` package for writing quantities and `mhchem` package for writing chem elements.

For convenient writing of your table I would use `tabularray` package `tabullarray` package:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{tableGreaterHeader}{RGB}{28, 69, 135}
\definecolor{tableHeader}{RGB}{211, 47, 47}
\definecolor{tableLineOne}{RGB}{245, 245, 245}
\definecolor{tableLineTwo}{RGB}{224, 224, 224}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\NewTableCommand\panel{
    \SetCell[c=17]{c,font=\bfseries,bg=tableHeader,fg=white}}
\NewTableCommand\material{%
    \SetRow{preto=\hspace{1em}}
    \SetCell[c=17]{l, font=\bfseries\itshape, bg=white, cmd={\hskip 2pt}}%
                          }


\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Minimal booktabs example.},
  label = {tab:table1}
                ]{vline{1-Z}={2-Y}{fg=white},
                  colspec = {*{17}{X[c, m, cmd={\hskip 0pt}, font=\footnotesize]}},
                  colsep  = 1.2pt,
                  cell{1}{1-3} = {r=2}{m},
                  row{even[3]} = {bg=tableLineOne},
                  row{odd[3]}  = {bg=tableLineTwo},
                  row{1,2}= {font=\scriptsize\bfseries,bg=tableGreaterHeader,fg=white},
                  rowhead=2
                  }
    \toprule
Base material
    &   Thickness 
        &   Amperage 
            &   \SetCell[c=5]{c}    Voltage 
                &   &   &   &   &   \SetCell[c=9]{c}    Wire feed speed
                                    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &                   \\
    \midrule[fg=white]
    &   &   & \ce{CO2}   
                & \ce{Ar} \qty{75}{\%} \ce{CO2} \qty{25}{\%}  
                    & \ce{He} + \ce{Ar} + \ce{CO2} 
                        & \ce{Ar}
                            & \ce{Ar} \qty{9}{\%}+  \ce{O2} \qty{2}{\%} 
                                & Steel .030  
                                    & Steel 0.035 
                                        & Steel 0.045 
                                            & Stainless steel 0.035
                                                & Stainless steel 0.045
                                                    & Stainless steel 0.063 
                                                        & \ce{Al} 4043 0.035
                                                            & \ce{Al} 4043 0.045
                                                                & \ce{Al} 4043 0.063    \\
    \midrule 
\panel{Short circuit transfer mode}
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
    \midrule
\material{Steel}
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
%
    & 22 ga & 40 - 55   & 16 - 17   & 15 - 16   & - & - & - & 90 - 100  & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
    & 20 ga & 50 - 60   & 17 - 18   & 15 - 16   & - & - & - & 120 - 135 & 105 - 115 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
    & 20 ga & 50 - 60   & 17 - 18   & 15 - 16   & - & - & - & 120 - 135 & 105 - 115 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
    & 18 ga & 70 - 80   & 18 - 19   & 16 - 17   & - & - & - & 150 - 175 & 140 - 160 & 70    & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
    & 16 ga & 90 - 110  & 19 - 20   & 17 - 18   & - & - & - & 220 - 250 & 180 - 220 & 90 - 110  & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
    & 14 ga & 120 - 130 & 20 - 21   & 17 - 18   & - & - & - & 250 - 340 & 240 - 260 & 120 - 130 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
    & 1/8   & 140 - 150 & 21 - 22   & 18 - 19   & - &   &   & - & 280 - 300 & 140 - 150 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
    & 3/16  & 160 - 170 & 21 - 22   & 18 - 19   & - & - & - & - & 320 - 340 & 160 - 175 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
    & 1/4   & 180 - 190 & 23 - 24   & 21 - 22   & - & - & - & - & 360 - 380 & 185 - 195 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
    & 5/16  & 200 - 210 & 23 - 24   & 21 - 22   & - & - & - & - & 400 - 420 & 210 - 220 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
    & 3/8   & 220 - 250 & 24 - 25   & 23 - 24   & - & - & - & - & 420 - 520 & 220 - 270 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
    & 1/2   & 300 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & 375 & - & - & - & - & - &   -   \\
\material{Stainless steel}
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
%
    & 18 ga & 50 - 60   & - & - & 19 - 20 & - & - & - & - & - & 120 - 150   & - & - & - & - & - \\
    & 16 ga & 70 - 80   & - & - & 19 - 20 & - & - & - & - & - & 180 - 205   & - & - & - & - & - \\
    & 14 ga & 90 - 110  & - & - & 20 - 21 & - & - & - & - & - & 230 - 275   & - & - & - & - & - \\
    & 12 ga & 120 - 130 & - & - & 20 - 21 & - & - & - & - & - & 300 - 325   & - & - & - & - & - \\
    & 3/16  & 140 - 150 & - & - & 21 - 22 & - & - & - & - & - & 350 - 375   & - & - & - & - & - \\
    & 1/4   & 160 - 170 & - & - & 21 - 22 & - & - & - & - & - & 400 - 425   & - & - & - & - & - \\
    & 5/16  & 180 - 190 & - & - & 21 - 22 & - & - & - & - & - & 450 - 475   & - & - & - & - & - \\
    & 3/8   & 200 - 210 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
    & 7/16  & 220 - 250 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
    & 1/2   & 300 - 325 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
    \midrule
\panel{Spray arc transfer mode}
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
    \midrule
\material{Steel}
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
%
    & 22 ga & 50 - 60 & - & - & - & - & - & 120 - 135   & 105 - 115 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
    & 20 ga & 70 - 80 & - & - & - & - & - & 150 - 175   & 140 - 160 &   70  & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
    & 18 ga & 90 - 110    & - & - & - & - & - & 220 - 250   & 180 - 220 & 90 - 110  & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
    & 16 ga & 120 - 130   & - & - & - & - & - & 250 - 340   & 240 - 260 & 120 - 130 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
    & 14 ga & 140 - 150   & - & - & - & - & - & - & 280 - 300   & 140 - 150 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
    & 1/8   & 160 - 170   & - & - & - & - & 23 - 24 & - & 320 - 340   & 160 - 175 & - & - & - & - & - & -   \\
    & 3/16  & 180 - 190   & - & - & - & - & 24 - 25 & - & 360 - 380   & 185 - 195 & - & - & - & - & - & -   \\
    & 1/4   & 200 - 210   & - & - & - & - & 24 - 25 & - & 400 - 420   & 210 - 220 & - & - & - & - & - & -   \\
    & 5/16  & 220 - 250   & - & - & - & - & 25 - 26 & - & 420 - 520   & 220 - 270 & - & - & - & - & - & -   \\
    & 3/8   & 300 & - & - & - & - &   26 - 27 & - & - & 375 & - & - & - & - & - & -   \\
    & 1/2   & 315 & - & - & - & - &   29 - 30 & - & - & 390 & - & - & - & - & - & -   \\
\material{Stainless steel}
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
    & 18 ga & 70 - 80   & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - &   180 - 205   & - & - & - & - & -   \\
    & 16 ga & 90 - 110  & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - &   230 - 275   & - & - & - & - & -   \\
    & 14 ga & 120 - 130 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - &   300 - 325   & - & - & - & - & -   \\
    & 12 ga & 140 - 150 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - &   350 - 375   & - & - & - & - & -   \\
    & 3/16  & 160 - 170 & - & - & - & - & 23 - 24   & - & - & - & 400 - 425 & - & - & - & - & -   \\
    & 1/4   & 180 - 190 & - & - & - & - & 24 - 25   & - & - & - & 450 - 475 & - & - & - & - & -   \\
    & 5/16  & 200 - 210 & - & - & - & - & 24 - 25   & - & - & - & - & 250 - 300 & - & - & - & -   \\
    & 3/8   & 250 - 275 & - & - & - & - & 25 - 26   & - & - & - & - & - & 140 - 170 & - & - & -   \\
    & 7/16  & 275 - 300 & - & - & - & - & 26 - 27   & - & - & - & - & - & 170 - 200 & - & - & -   \\
    & 1/2   & 300 - 325 & - & - & - & - & 27 - 32   & - & - & - & - & - & 200 - 230 & - & - & -   \\
\material{Aluminum}
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
%
    & 1/8   & 110 - 130 & - & - & - & 21 - 22 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & 350 - 400   & 240 - 270 & -   \\
    & 3/16  & 140 - 150 & - & - & - & 23 - 24 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & 425 - 450   & 300 - 325 & -   \\
    & 1/4   & 180 - 210 & - & - & - & 24 - 25 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & 350 - 370   & 170 - 185   \\
    & 5/16  & 200 - 230 & - & - & - & 26 - 27 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & 400 - 425   & 200 - 210   \\
    & 3/8   & 220 - 250 & - & - & - & 26 - 28 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & 450 - 480   & 220 - 230   \\
    & 7/16  & 280 & - & - & - & 28 - 29 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & 240 - 270   \\
    & 1/2   & 300 & - & - & - & 29 - 30 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & 290 - 300   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]