# Contents in pdf reader use a "greeklish" display when writing greek

Tags: table-of-contents, viewers, greek

I am creating a greek document using package babel. The main problem is that the contents the pdf viewer creates are not displayed in greek, but in "greeklish".

**Okular**

[image: okular]

**Adobe Reader**

[image: adobe reader]

At first I thought that it was `Okular`'s issue but I get the same behaviour on `adobe reader` and `adobe acrobat`, so I don't think that has to do with the reader.

My `TeXLive` version is `TeX 3.14159265` and I am using `pdfLatex`.

A simple code is

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}
%\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}
 \tableofcontents
 \chapter{Περίληψη}
%  \begin{otherlanguage}{greek}
% \addchap{\texorpdfstring{Per'ilhyh}{Περίληψη}}
% Per'ilhyh
% \end{otherlanguage}
  \section{Πρώτη Ενότητα}
  \section{Δεύτερη Ενότητα}
 \chapter{Δεύτερο Κεφάλαιο}
  \section{Πρώτη Ενότητα}
  \section{Δεύτερη Ενότητα}
 \chapter{Τρίτο Κεφάλαιο}
  \section{Πρώτη Ενότητα}
  \section{Δεύτερη Ενότητα}
\end{document}
```

I've tried to use options `unicode` or `pdfencoding=auto` to the `hyperref` package, but without any luck. I've also changed the encoding from `iso-8859-7` to `utf8` but I get an error

> `! Argument of \UTFviii@three@octets has an extra }.
>   &lt;inserted text&gt; 
>                   \par 
>   l.13  \chapter{��������}
>         Runaway argument?`

Any idea why is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: I think this is a case for `\chapter[\texorpdfstring{Πρώτο κεφάλαιο}{proto kefalaio}]{Πρώτο κεφάλαιο}`

Comment: You need to load `hyperref` of course.

Comment: @Johannes_B : This doesn't change it. instead of having `Pr'wto Kef'alaio` I now have `proto kefalaio` while I want `Πρώτο Κεφάλαιο`. You are right about `hyperef`. I've edited my question.

Comment: [Greek pdf-bookmarks with greektex package; is it possible?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52614)

Comment: Why are you insisting in using iso-8859-7 instead of UTF-8? If I use UTF-8 and `\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}`, I get the right thing.

Comment: @egreg It says so when doing `texdoc kerkis`. Someone should inform the maintainer about this.

Comment: I would drop `kerkis.sty` completely. There are other (better?) fonts out there, especially in the open type section.

Comment: @Johannes_B The date I get of README.html in the Kerkis suite is 2006-01-09; not particularly up-to-date. Many things have changed in Greek support since then.

Comment: @egreg `\ProvidesFile{kerkis.sty}[2000/02/25 v1.5 Package `kerkis.sty']` Even worse. That's why i recommended to drop its usage.

Comment: @Johannes_B There's nothing really wrong with `kerkis.sty`.

Comment: @egreg : eventualy using `utf8` along `unicode` option in `hyperref` worked. What I was doing wrong was using another encoding in my editor! Do you think that I have to give an answer emphasizing that?

Comment: @Thanos The answer is already in the question I linked. There are surely others dealing with matching the file encoding with the option to `inputenc`.

Comment: @egreg : The keypoint(or the new that an asnwer will add) however, is to change the editor's encoding.