# Numeration of framed and non-framed theorems

Tags: enumerate

In the attached picture you can see that boxed theorem has the same numaration as the theorem which follows it. Also Corollary have a numeration.
I am wondering how to give a proper numeration to all theorems? I mean the boxed theorem should be 1 and the next one is 2 and so on.
I'd like to have Corollary without any numeration.

Thank you so much!

Please see my code

```
\documentclass{article}
%\documentclass[16pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,text={16.5cm,25.2cm},centering]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\onehalfspacing
%\doublespacing
\usepackage{mathtools}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xMapsto}[2][]{\ext@arrow 0599{\Mapstofill@}{#1}{#2}}
\def\Mapstofill@{\arrowfill@{\Mapstochar\Relbar}\Relbar\Rightarrow}
\makeatother


\newcommand{\RN}[1]{%
  \textup{\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral#1}}%
}

\newmdtheoremenv{theo}{Theorem}

\newenvironment{claim}[1]{\par\noindent\underline{Claim:}\space#1}{}
\newenvironment{claimproof}[1]{\par\noindent\underline{Proof:}\space#1}{\hfill $\blacksquare$}

\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\smallO{
  \mathchoice
    {{\scriptstyle\mathcal{O}}}% \displaystyle
    {{\scriptstyle\mathcal{O}}}% \textstyle
    {{\scriptscriptstyle\mathcal{O}}}% \scriptstyle
    {\scalebox{.7}{$\scriptscriptstyle\mathcal{O}$}}%\scriptscriptstyle
  }

\usepackage{stackengine}
\parskip 1em
\newcommand\stackequal[2]{%
  \mathrel{\stackunder[2pt]{\stackon[4pt]{=}{$\scriptscriptstyle#1$}}{%
  $\scriptscriptstyle#2$}}}

\title{\textbf{Inverse function theorem}}
\author{}
\date{}


\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Apparently you defined two environments to write theorems, and they use two different counters. But if you want anyone to be able to actually answer your question, you should provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/201628): without seeing your code it is impossible to know how you defined your theorem environments.

Comment: @Vincent, I uploaded my code also. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `\newtheorem`, you can specify a counter to follow in an optional argument between the two mandatory ones, so you can use that to make your environment `theorem` follow the counter of `theo`. Also, the starred version `\newtheorem*` produces unnumbered environments, so you can use that for corollaries.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,text={16.5cm,25.2cm},centering]{geometry}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newmdtheoremenv{theo}{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{theorem}[theo]{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{corollary}{Corollary}

\parskip 1em

\begin{document}

\begin{theo}
A framed theorem.
\end{theo}

\begin{theorem}
Another theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{corollary}
A corollary.
\end{corollary}

\end{document}
```

As an unrelated side comment, I think you should consider learning better what is in your preamble if you don't really know what the packages are doing. Then you can clean up your preamble a little. For example:

- You load both `amsfonts` and `amssymb`, but `amssymb` already loads `amsfonts`;
- You load both `amsmath` and `mathtools`, but `mathtools` already loads `amsmath`, and you even load `mathtools` twice;
- You explicitly load `inputenc` with option `utf8` twice, but it is [automatically loaded](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/641193/201628).

Comment: Thank you! It worked but may I ask you few questions: why `\newtheorem{theorem}[theo]{Theorem}` has 3 parenthesis but `\newmdtheoremenv{theo}{Theorem}` only? And what is meaning of each of these parenthesis?

Comment: @ZFR The extra one is what I explained at the beginning of my answer: it's the optional argument which specifies a counter to follow. These three arguments of `\newtheorem` are respectively the name of the environment, a (optional) counter to follow, and the text written at the beginning of the environment. I think it's the same for `\newmdtheoremenv`, but I'm not sure (I usually work with `tcolorbox` rather than `mdframed`). If you want more information, you should read the documentations of `amsthm` and `mdframed` on CTAN.

Comment: Thank you! I'll accept your answer!